# Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados

Tags: javascript, matemática, ponto-flutuante

### Problema

Testem aí nos consoles dos seus browsers:

```
1067.11-1000 = 67.1099999999999
```

O correto seria `67.11`

1. Alguém poderia me explicar isso?
2. E como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: As respostas adicionadas já são bastante completas, por isso não vou postar mais uma. Mas se quiser ler mais sobre o assunto e perceber porque é que operações em vírgula-flutuante podem ser "traiçoeiras" e devem ser usadas com cuidado, sugiro este artigo:
http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/28/14/29/PDF/floating-point-article.pdf

Comment: Fiz uma resposta mostrando exatamente o que está acontecendo na memória do computador, para que fique claro o que está acontecendo. Espero que ajude!

Comment: Se quiser ainda mais detalhes, poderia mostrar também como é feita a conversão entre double/string... acho que só faltou isso para fechar a resposta que dei.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Esta conversão poderia ser mostrada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264529/3082

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## Resposta curta

Isso ocorre por causa de uma imprecisão na conversão do valor 1067.11 para a
representação do número em memória... imprecisão esta, que é revelada ao
subtrair o valor 1000.

## Resposta longa

### Fatores da imprecisão

Imprecisões numéricas ocorrem por uma variedade de fatores,
que decorrem da forma com que tais números são representados pelo computador.

Números com ponto flutuante, nos sistemas modernos são geralmente
representados de acordo com a norma
[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) de forma nativa. O javascript especificamente, [usa o `double`
para representar todos os números](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605925/does-javascript-have-double-floating-point-number-precision).

No caso do [`double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) da norma [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), imprecisões são causadas por
dois fatores:

- Quantidade de espaço para representar o número é finita. No caso corrente,
  esta limitação não é o que causa a imprecisão.
- Base numérica do expoente é 2, que não pode ser alinhada com a base do
  número original `1067.11` que está na base 10. Esse é o causador da
  imprecisão no caso corrente.

Para entender melhor temos de ver como exatamente é representado o tipo `double`.

### Componentes de um `double`

O [`double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) da norma [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) é formado da seguinte maneira:

- sinal: 1 bit para o sinal
- expoente: inteiro de 11 bits,
  para indicar o valor do expoente deslocado 1023 unidades, ou então
  um dos dois valores com significados especiais:
  0x000 para valores subnormais e zero;
  0x7FF para representar infinito e NaN.
  (i.e. 2<sup>x - 1023</sup>, onde x é o valor inteiro do campo)
- mantissa: 52 bits, para valores normais do expoente, representa um valor
  racional que vai de 1.0 inclusive até 2.0 exclusive, matematicamente `[1, 2[`.
  Para o valor do expoente 0x000, então representa valores subnormais (i.e.
  menores que o menor valor normal representável) ou zero; Para o valor do
  expoente 0x7FF representa infinito se for 0, ou NaN se for diferente de 0.

### Por que imprecisão aparece só após subtrair 1000

Apesar de não parecer, o número 1067.11 **não pode ser representado exatamente**
pelo javascript. Então como é que o javascript consegue converter esse número
de volta para string, exatamente como "1067.11"?

```
alert(1067.11); // vai mostrar "1067.11", como é possível então?
```

Isso ocorre pois a implementação do javascript é esperta... na hora de
converter para string, mostra o valor **mais curto** que seria representável por
este valor de `double`.

Isso acontece pois um único valor de `double` resulta de várias conversões de
string para double:

```
1067.1100000000000000000001
1067.11000000000000001
1067.11000000000001
1067.11
1067.10999999999978626875
1067.1099999999997862687453
1067.10999999999978626874509
1067.1099999999998999553285190717
```

Ao escrever qualquer um dos números acima no console do chrome, o resultado é
`1067.11`... pois esta é a string mais curta.

**Mas a verdade é que você está sendo enganando!**

- O valor exato da string "1067.11" convertida para `double` é `1067.1099999999998999553285190717`.
- O valor exato menos 1000 é `67.1099999999998999553285190717`.
- O valor mais curto representável pelo double anterior é `67.1099999999999`.
- **Conclusão:**

  ```
                            1067.11 - 1000 == 67.1099999999999
                              é **EXATAMENTE** o mesmo que
  1067.1099999999998999553285190717 - 1000 == 67.1099999999998999553285190717
  ```

Ou seja:

```
    O que realmente acontece na memória  =>    O que é mostrado para você
    1067.1099999999998999553285190717    =>    1067.11
  - 1000                                 =>  - 1000
    ---------------------------------          ------------------
      67.1099999999998999553285190717    =>      67.1099999999999
```

**Referências**

Minhas fontes de informações e aprendizado:

- [Double-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)
- [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)
- [How to manually parse a floating point number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85223/how-to-manually-parse-a-floating-point-number-from-a-string)
- [Does JavaScript have double floating point number precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605925/does-javascript-have-double-floating-point-number-precision)
- [Everything you never wanted to know about JavaScript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqHDDtVYJRI&list=PLyG7wDhlOL-nZBTZ7oFGgrDNpEowoo4PO&index=107)
- [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)
- [IEEE-754 Floating-Point Conversion](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html)
- [Binary floating point and .NET](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 29):

> Fonte:
>   http://www.guj.com.br/8905-problemas-no-calculo-com-javascript

O porquê disso é o seguinte.

O computador não trabalha bem com casas decimais. Como você sabe, os dados são representados internamente no formato binário.

O número 4, por exemplo, é representado pelo computador assim:

```
100 (onde 1x2^2 + 0x2^1 + 0x2^0 = 4)
```

Como é representado um número com casas decimais? O número fica impreciso porque, depois da vírgula, cada bit ligado representa 2^-n, onde n é o número da casa contada da direita pra esquerda, a partir do 1. Assim, o número 2,5 seria representado em binário por:

```
2 = 10 
0,5 = 0.1
2,5 = 10.1
```

Agora, considere o esforço de escrever uma fração que não é múltipla de 2, como 0,3, usando potências de 2:

A primeira potência que usaríamos poderia ser 1/4, que é 0,25.
Para melhorar a precisão, podemos somar 1/32, que é 0,03125.
Obteríamos então, 0,28125. E se quiséssemos aumentar ainda mais a precisão?
Daria para somar 1/64, que é 0,015625, e obteríamos 0,296875...
Nosso número já está assim: 0,3 = 0,010011

Poderíamos continuar somando com divisores múltiplos de 2 cada vez maiores, mas dificilmente chegaríamos em 0,3. Esse comportamento assintótico é extremamente inconveniente e, para uma base como 2, extremamente frequente.

Com isso, vemos que o sistema de base 2 é muitíssimo pobre para representar números que não podem ser obtidos por frações de 2. E daí que vem essa imprecisão toda. O que o computador faz é aumentar (muito) o número de bits quando contas envolvendo floats são feitas. Isso atenua o problema, mas não o resolve. Pequenas dicas de programação (como multiplicar antes de dividir, quando possível) também ajudam.

Entretanto, muitas vezes não é suficiente. O Java (mas não o JavaScript) fornece classes (BigDecimal e BigInteger) para que você manipule números de precisão arbitrária. Nesse caso, os cálculos são feitos de maneira indireta, e são muito mais lentos comparados à maneira primitiva. Mas ainda sim, quebram um galhão.

Isso explica o seu número estranho. Não é um bug do JavaScript, é a forma que os computadores funcionam. O mesmo problema irá se repetir em todas as linguagens de programação.

Comment: `Nesse caso, os cálculos são feitos por software(...)` Isso soa tão estranho.

Comment: Boa, esta pergunta e resposta estavam faltando no site. Só acho que valeria a pena mencionar algumas questões mais "burocráticas", como o uso do padrão IEEE 754 no js.

Comment: Mais uma coisa: a resposta ficaria mais precisa se você indicasse que em Javascript, existe um único tipo numérico (`Number`). Esse tipo armazena valores como ponto flutuante. Ele não armazena valores inteiros, mas sim potências. Por isso, qualquer cálculo se baseia em aproximações. Bônus se você citar as funções que permitem arredondar resultados como o do exemplo para forçar o uso do inteiro mais próximo.

Comment: Uma referência excelente sobre o assunto para quem lê inglês: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: _"O mesmo problema irá se repetir em todas as linguagens de programação."_ Descordo desta sua colocação. Isso é uma questão de como cada linguagem trata dados numéricos e não um problema de como o computador armazena números e coisa e tal.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck  isso é um problema de como o computador armazena números, não tem a ver com a linguagem. É matematicamente impossível representar todos os números reais com números binários.

Comment: @carloscinelli Mesmo assim não justifica o argumento de "todas as linguagens". O BigDecimal do Java por exemplo não tem perda de precisão. De qualquer forma, problemas de precisão geralmente ocorrem quando temos números em escalas diferentes de precisão, logo não é um problema do computador e sim falta de pudor do desenvolvedor ao realizar suas operações.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck a necessidade de se criar uma biblioteca/pacote de precisão arbitrária decorre do fato de computadores armazenarem informação de forma binária, não é algo da lógica ou sintaxe ou etc da linguagem em si. Com essas bibliotecas você aumenta a precisão dos números reais nos computadores, mas não consegue representá-los exatamente nunca.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Na verdade, o BigDecimal do Java varia de comportamento. Se você usar o construtor que recebe um double ele também opera internamente de forma "errônea", o próprio [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) orienta nisso. O mesmo ocorre no método [BigDecimal#valueOf(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)).

Answer (score 17):

Acho que a primeira parte da pergunta já está bem respondida.. :)

Quanto à segunda, no JavaScript você pode formatar o seu número em ponto-fixo utilizando o método [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

O método recebe um parâmetro indicando a quantidade de dígitos:

```
(1067.11-1000).toFixed(2);
```

nesse caso, o resultado será a string `"67.11"`.

Para explicitamente trabalhar com ele novamente como número:

```
resultado = Number( (1067.11 - 1000).toFixed(2) );
```

Comment: Boa, deu certo ;)

Comment: Todos explicaram, mas o unico que resolveu foi você, valeu