# Por que 0.1 + 0.05 não é igual a 0.15? Que soluções podem ser utilizadas no R?

Tags: r, ponto-flutuante

No `R`:

```
0.1+0.05 == 0.15
[1] FALSE
```

Por que isso ocorre? Como contornar a situação (funções e pacotes para lidar com pontos flutuantes)?

***Edição:***

[Esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-calculo-com-numeros-quebrados) já contém respostas gerais sobre ponto flutuante, deste modo restringi a presente pergunta para soluções no `R`.

Comment: Ocorre o mesmo se você usar `(0.1+0.05) == 0.15`?

Comment: Pelo mesmo motivo descrito [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/3117)

Comment: Prezados, para não parecer que a questão é repetida, vou restringir o escopo da pergunta para soluções apenas no `R`. Notem que a outra pergunta não apresenta soluções para o `R`- pacotes, funções etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eu não conseguiria explicar melhor que o Guilherme Bernal porque isso ocorre. Por essa razão, vou me limitar ao como contornar a situação dentro do `R`.

Para entender como o `R` "vê" 0.1, 0.05, 0.1 + 0.05 e 0.15, use o comando `format`

```
format(c(0.1, 0.05, 0.1 + 0.05, 0.15), digits = 20)
[1] "0.100000000000000005551" "0.050000000000000002776"
[3] "0.150000000000000022204" "0.149999999999999994449"
```

Segundo o [R-faq](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) o modo de fazer a comparação é através do comando `all.equal` e não do operador `==`

```
all.equal(0.1 + 0.05, 0.15)
[1] TRUE
```

A documentação de `all.equal` recomenda que, dentro de um `if`, você use `all.equal` juntamente com `isTRUE`, assim:

```
if (isTRUE(all.equal(0.1 + 0.05, 0.15))) {
    message("0.1 + 0.05 = 0.15")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Por que a grande maioria das linguagens de programação representa pontos flutuantes usando o padrão [IEEE754](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) ou algo similar. O ponto é que os números são representados da seguinte forma:

```
(1.M) × 2E
```

Sendo que `M` e `E` são inteiros escritos com um número fixo de casas. Sendo assim:

```
0,0510 = 0.0000110011001100110011001100110011...   (vira uma dízima)
0,0510 = 1.1001100110011001 × 2(1012)
            M = 1001100110011001
            E = 0000000000000101
```

O grande problema é que é uma dízima, alguns algarismos foram inevitavelmente perdidos na conversão. Convertendo isso de volta para um base 10 você terá: `0.049999713897705078125`. É bem perto de `0.05`. Se você fizer o mesmo para `0.1` também encontrará um resultado bem próximo. Somando eles você terá algo próximo a `0.15`. O problema quando você testa a igualdade é que dois valores diferentes mas bem próximos a `0.15` são ainda diferentes.

Por isso nunca teste se dois pontos flutuantes são iguais diretamente. Uma boa forma de testar é:

```
abs(a - b) < delta
```

Onde `delta` é um valor pequeno, mas não zero.

Outras boas alternativas (especialmente se você precisa de valores exatos como em cálculos monetários) é usar um número de ponto fixo (ou seja, representar como `A/B`, onde `A` é um inteiro que você guarda na memória e `B` é uma constante fixa, por exemplo `100`) ou representar com um par de inteiros, formando números racionais.

Answer (score 2):

Em um teste realizado com Java, o resultado quando sendo do tipo double retorna:

```
0.15000000000000002
```

Mas quando utilizamos o float, temos que 0.1F + 0.05F é igual a 0.15F:

```
System.out.println(0.1F + 0.05F == 0.15F);
```

Sem dúvida cada SO e linguagem tem um tratamento particular para números com ponto flutuante, portando não havendo uma solução universal.

Answer (score 2):

Isto deve-se à conversão de números reais em base decimal para números de vírgula flutuante em base binária (de acordo com a norma IEEE 754).  De forma geral, isto acontece quando o número não é uma soma de expoentes de 2.

Convém compreender que floats são representados de forma binária, tipicamente com 32 ou 64 bits:

- Bit de sinal (0 - positivo, 1 - negativo)
- Expoente (8 ou 11 bits)
- Mantissa ou parte fraccionária (23 ou 52 bits)

Em que a fórmula é:

> Base 2: (-1)<sup>sinal</sup> × 10<sup>expoente - (1111111 ou 1111111111)</sup> × 1.mantissa

Excepções:

> - +0 e -0 têm expoente = 0 e mantissa = 0
> - +Inf e -Inf têm expoente = tudo 1s e mantissa = 0
> - NaNs têm expoente tudo 1s e mantissa diferente de 0

Estes utilitários ([[1]](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/), [[2]](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)) ajudam a compreender a representação de 0.10 e 0.05 em single floats (32 bits).  Experimente com 4.0, 2.0, (expoentes positivos de 2) 1.0 (expoente 0, codificado como 127), 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, (expoentes negativos de 2), 0.375 (soma de 0.125 três vezes) e depois com 0.1, 0.01, 0.3, etc.

Por exemplo, com o [segundo utilitário](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/), clique em "Add An Analyzer".  Seleccione "decimal" no da esquerda e introduza 0.1.  Seleccione "binary" no da direita e introduza 0.000110011001100110011001101.

Neste caso, observamos um arredondamento:

> 0,1<sub>10</sub>
>
> = 0,000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100…<sub>2</sub>
>
> ≈ 0,000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101<sub>2</sub> (arredondamento)
>
> = Base 2: (-1)<sup>**0**</sup> × 10<sup>**111 1011** - 111 1111</sup> × 1,**100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101**

A forma de converter este número de volta para base decimal é semelhante à dos inteiros, só que cada bit após a vírgula é multiplicado com um expoente negativo de 2:

> Σ<sub>i</sub> b<sub>i</sub> × 2<sup>i</sup>, i ∈ ℕ : min ≤ i ≤ max

Neste caso, min = -27, max = 0

> 0×2<sup>0</sup> + 0×2<sup>-1</sup> + 0×2<sup>-2</sup> + 0×2<sup>-3</sup>
>
> + 1×2<sup>-4</sup> + 1×2<sup>-5</sup> + 0×2<sup>-6</sup> + 0×2<sup>-7</sup>
>
> + 1×2<sup>-8</sup> + 1×2<sup>-9</sup> + 0×2<sup>-10</sup> + 0×2<sup>-11</sup>
>
> + 1×2<sup>-12</sup> + 1×2<sup>-13</sup> + 0×2<sup>-14</sup> + 0×2<sup>-15</sup>
>
> + 1×2<sup>-16</sup> + 1×2<sup>-17</sup> + 0×2<sup>-18</sup> + 0×2<sup>-19</sup>
>
> + 1×2<sup>-20</sup> + 1×2<sup>-21</sup> + 0×2<sup>-22</sup> + 0×2<sup>-23</sup>
>
> + 1×2<sup>-24</sup> + 1×2<sup>-25</sup> + 0×2<sup>-26</sup> + 1×2<sup>-27</sup>
>
> = 0,100000001490116119384765625
>
> ≈ 0,1 (arredondamento)

Ainda que não houvessem arredondamentos logo nos dados de entrada, não quer dizer que os resultados não possam ser diferentes do esperado.  Por exemplo, as somas e subtracções sofrem muito mais devido à diferença do expoente do que as multiplicações e as divisões.

Muitas vezes, o que nós vemos como uma comparação de igualdade (x = 2,5) em termos matemáticos tem de ser uma comparação de intervalo em termos de vírgula flutuante (2,5 - ε ≤ x ≤ 2,5 + ε).

Este ε (épsilon) deve ser um valor na escala do valor que estamos a verificar.

Não faz sentido que a diferença seja o menor flutuante possível, porque se o fizer, vai notar que 2,5 ± *menor flutuante possível* ≈ 2,5.  Isto é, a soma de facto é como se não acontecesse, porque os valores estão muito distantes na escala.  A precisão é finita, como seria de esperar.

Por outro lado, também não é muito bom usar o float imediatamente abaixo ou acima (a não ser que queiramos **mesmo** tal precisão), mas talvez o segundo, terceiro, sei lá, décimo float abaixo ou acima.

Em termos práticos, deve ser uma função a fazer este trabalho, senão mesmo uma macro para quando o termo de comparação é constante.  Isto porque não é comum as linguagens de programação terem sintaxe para floats em binário, como 10,1<sub>2</sub> (2,5<sub>10</sub>), quanto mais um tal single-float 10,1000000000000000000100<sub>2</sub> (8º single-floats acima de 2,5) ou 10,0111111111111111111000<sub>2</sub> (8º single-float abaixo de 2,5).  Ou mesmo que a linguagem até tenha sintaxe, não é nada legível ou prática.