# Como criar matriz inversa no R

Tags: r, matriz

Para conseguirmos obter a inversa de uma matriz, podemos usar diferentes comandos do R `solve()`, `ginv()`, etc, porém, ao tentar utilizar esses comando, ocorre um erro onde achamos que o problema deve ser porque há valores negativos na matriz, já que na descrição dos comandos eles especificam que devemos achar a inversa para matrizes positivo-definidas. Como conseguimos resolver essa questão?

Comment: Você poderia exemplificar com código, ou com o erro que está encontrando.

Comment: X_i<-chol2inv(X), onde X é uma matriz de dimensão 1000x3
Usamos o comando chol2inv() da nossa matriz original na tentativa de achar o valor de (X'X)^-1 e encontramos uma matriz de dimensão 3x3, que é o esperado. Certo?
Dado que esse problema foi resolvido, precisamos criar um vetor y com dimensão 1000x1, y sendo uma função (processo gerador de dados). Podemos definir y como a pgd (y<-a+bx+cz) e em seguida definir suas dimensões com (dim(y)=c(1000,1,1)? Fizemos isso e não temos certeza se está correto.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, e acrescente lá.

Comment: Felipe, não está muito claro qual é o problema, se você conseguir colocar um exemplo do código fica mais fácil de ajudar. Veja aqui como melhorar a pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-minimo-reproduzivel-em-r/825#825

Answer (score 2):

Felipe, não está muito claro qual é o problema, o ideal seria você colocar o código com o (possível) erro. Mas seguem algumas maneiras de se inverter uma matriz no `R`:

Gerando uma base de dados de exemplo:

```
### constante
c <- rep(1, 1000)

### x ~ N(1,2)
set.seed(1)
x <-rnorm(1000, 1,2) 

### w ~ N(1,2)
set.seed(2)
w <- rnorm(1000, 1, 2)

X = cbind(c,x,w)
```

Invertendo (X'X):

```
### com solve:
a <- solve(t(X)%*%X)

### com ginv:
b <-ginv(t(X)%*%X)

### com choleski:
c <- chol2inv(chol(t(X)%*%X))

### com qr:
d <-qr.solve(qr(t(X)%*%X))
```

Comparando todas para ver que são iguais:

```
### primeiro vamos tirar os dimnames para comparar somente os numeros
dimnames(a) <- NULL
dimnames(d) <- NULL

### comparando
all.equal(a,b,c,d)
[1] TRUE
```

É preciso usar o comando `all.equal` por causa de [erros de ponto flutuante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6857/por-que-0-1-0-05-nao-e-igual-a-0-15-que-solucoes-podem-ser-utilizadas-no-r).

No caso de estimar os coeficientes de uma regressão (se você não quer usar a função `lm`), você pode usar `qr.coef`:

```
### y = 10 + 5x + 2w + u, u~N(0,1)
set.seed(3)
y <- 10 + 5*x +2*w + rnorm(1000)

### estimando os betas
B <- qr.coef(qr(X), y)
B
       c        x        w 
9.994012 5.019442 1.994124
```

Answer (score 0):

se você que inverter `X'X`, a maneira mais simples é usando `solve()`:

```
    # crio uma matriz qualquer (3 colunas, 100 linhas)
    X = cbind(1, rnorm(100), runif(100))

    # invertenddo X'X
    a = solve(t(X)%*%X)

    # invertendo a decomposição QR
    b = chol2inv(X)

    # é a mesma coisa?
    a==b
          [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
    [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```