# Realização de contas de ponto flutuante em JavaScript com precisão absoluta

Tags: javascript, ponto-flutuante

Estou trabalhando com valores financeiros e na hora de realizar operações matemáticas no JavaScript, os valores não são os esperados.

```
 console.log(11.8-10.2)
 1.6000000000000014
```

Gostaria de saber como resolver este problema de precisão para ter sempre um retorno com 2 casas decimais (`1.60` neste caso).

Não pode ser `toFixed()` pois existem casos que ele dá um valor pra baixo, por exemplo:

```
 console.log(39.8 - 28.2)
 11.599999999999998
```

No caso queria um retorno de `11.60`.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-calculo-com-numeros-quebrados)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript executa todas as operações numéricas usando matemática de ponto flutuante (pois o tipo é Double compativel com a definição `IEEE`). Utilizando números de ponto flutuante funciona bem para problemas de Engenharia e Simulação onde podemos admitir um erro infinitesimal. Erros de arredondamento podem ser ignorados nestes caso. Porém se você precisa de saída de dados numéricos de alta precisão (como a realização de `cálculos financeiros` por exemplo, onde um único centavo pode causar um erro na Contabilidade), você precisa de usar uma biblioteca de Calculo em Decimal como faz o java com o tipo `BigDecimal`.

Como observado pelo autor da pergunta existe uma [Arbitrary-precision decimals library for JavaScript](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) disponível no `github`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js

por exemplo

Comment: isso mesmo @felipemuner

Answer (score 13):

Apesar da resposta já ter sido dada, acredito que valha a pena uma explicação do motivo pelo qual essas imprecisões ocorrem.

O padrão IEEE 754 ([aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) e [aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)), que define os números com ponto flutuante, como `float` ou `double` (Java, C, C++, C#), ou os números gerais do JavaScript, trata os números internamente em uma notação científica, cuja base é sempre 2.

Como a base é 2, e a *mantissa* deve ser sempre maior ou igual a 1 e menor que a base, então ela acabou sendo fixada em 1.

Assim:

- O número 4 é tratado como 1,0 × 2 <sup>2</sup>
- O número 10 é tratado como 1,25 × 2 <sup>3</sup>
- O número 6,25 é tratado como 1,5625 × 2 <sup>2</sup>

Para armazenar esse valor, contudo, a precisão não é infinita, sendo limitada a uma quantidade específica de bits. `float` usa 32 bits e `double` (ou os números em JavaScript)  usa 64 bits, divididos da seguinte forma:

32 bits: `s|eeeeeeee|23 × m` (1 bit para o sinal, 8 para o expoente e 23 para a mantissa)

64 bits: `s|eeeeeeeeeee|52 × m` (1 bit para o sinal, 11 para o expoente e 52 para a mantissa)

Como a base é fixa em 1, a mantissa armazena apenas sua parte fracionária.

Para converter da notação binária, para uma representação decimal, cada bit na mantissa deve ser multiplicado por uma potência de 2 negativa. O primeiro bit deve ser multiplicado por 2 <sup>-1</sup>, o segundo por 2 <sup>-2</sup> e assim por diante.

Com isso, uma mantissa igual à `10010000000000000000000` (utilizando 23 bits por simplicidade), quando convertida para decimal se torna:

2 <sup>-1</sup> + 2 <sup>-4</sup> = 0,5 + 0,0625 = 0,5625

Como o número 1 é implícito, então essa mantissa realmente vale 1,5625

A partir daí surgem diversos problemas com números aparentemente simples.

O número 3,2, por exemplo. Em notação científica com base 2, se torna 1,6 × 2 <sup>1</sup>.

Até aqui, sem problemas, porém, o problema surge na hora de converter essa mantissa para binário. Sua parte fracionária deveria ser representável através de uma soma de potências negativas de base 2. Acontece que 0,6 não pode ser representado por uma soma finita de potências negativas de base 2. Repare em sua representação binária (utilizando 23 bits por simplicidade):

`10011001100110011001100`

Se dividida corretamente, pode-se perceber que é uma repetição de `1001`:

`1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 100`

A última repetição, porém, é *truncada* para `100`. Contudo, mesmo que não estivesse *truncada*, a soma dessas potências ainda não seria 0,6. Similar ao que ocorre quando se divide 1 por 3.

Para um computador utilizando o tipo de dados `float`, o número 3,2 é, internamente, armazenado como 3,1999998092651367 (aprox.).

Com `double`, a única diferença está na quantidade de 9's que seguiriam o 1 (existiriam mais 9's). Mas ainda assim estaria "errado".

Agora, eventualmente, números aparentemente "estranhos" para nós poderiam ser corretamente armazenados. Por exemplo, 3,13671875.

Transformado em notação científica: 1,2841796875 × 2 <sup>2</sup>.

Apesar da quantidade aparentemente grande de casas decimais, esse número é perfeitamente armazenável em uma variável `float` ou `double`, pois 0,2841796875 é uma soma de quatro potências negativas de 2:

2 <sup>-2</sup> + 2 <sup>-5</sup> + 2 <sup>-9</sup> + 2 <sup>-10</sup>

No formato binário de 23 bits: `01001000110000000000000`

Se você quiser testar outros números, é possível utilizar um material interativo online que eu disponibilizo a meus alunos: [Ponto Flutuante IEEE 754](http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/Aula/Flutuante.html).

E aqui http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/Aula/Flutuante2.html tem quatro tutoriais ensinando a fazer esse processo manualmente.

Lá, eu utilizo o formato de 32 bits, mas já dá para se ter uma ideia de como funcionaria o formato de 64 bits.

Answer (score 6):

Pode usar o [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para criar uma string com os zeros que pretende:

```
var numero = 11.8-10.2;
console.log(numero); // 1.6000000000000014 (numero)
var numeroTratado = numero.toFixed(2);
console.log(numeroTratado); //1.60 (string)
```

Note que assim não vai ter um número, mas sim uma string. Se quiser ter um numero, o javascript vai sempre tirar o ultimo zero.

Para ter um numero arredondado às decimas pode combinar o [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) com o [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
console.log(parseFloat(numeroTratado)); //1.6 (numero)
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/hG43p/)

---

**Se não pretender arredondar**, mas ter sempre duas casa decimais pode usar o [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) assim:

```
var numero = 39.8 - 28.2;
var partes = (numero + '').split('.'); // ['11', '599999999999998']
var parteCorrigida = partes[1].slice(0, 2); // '59'
var numeroFinal = [partes[0], parteCorrigida].join('.')
console.log(numeroFinal); //11.59
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/PHBmV/)

Comment: foi a primeira saída que pensei Sergio, porém ela não é válida pelo motivo que editei minha pergunta.

existem casos que ele dá uma aproximação abaixo do esperado como :

console.log(39.8 - 28.2)
 11.599999999999998
ao inves de 11.60

Comment: @felipemuner: __http://jsfiddle.net/hG43p/__ a mim dá-me `11.60`como você quer...

Comment: Mesmo assim cara, estou trabalhando com contas financeiras o mais certo é o que o @joaoparana disse ali embaixo... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: @felipemuner, nesse caso a sua pergunta devia ter explicado isso, e os cenários possíveis de numeros. Com a informação que colocou na pergunta respondí ao que pediu...

Comment: Sim, é que não sabia a melhor maneira de formular a pergunta. Obrigado mesmo assim..

e vc concorda que n posso trabalhar 'forçando o arredondamento com toFixed()' ? tem casos que ele poderá distorcer o resultado desejado.

Comment: @felipemuner sempre que trabalha com numeros tem de escolher entre arredondar ou não arredondar. Quando retira casa decimais está a arredondar... Eu dei duas hipóteses, você é quem sabe melhor que cálculos são.

Comment: Acho que o OP não entendeu direito a matemática. o toFixed seria um caminho perfeito, mesmo para cálculos contábeis. Basta ajustar o fator de multiplicação. Se estiver com problema no cálculo de centavos, por exemplo, aí é questão de fazer o arredondamento de maneira consistente (decidir se é Floor, se é 4/5, se é próximo par, etc).