# Valores em tempo real na classe input type="range"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bem, tentei fazer os valores em um `input type="range"` demostrar em tempo real ao usuário selecionar mais não estou conseguindo. com jquery também é do mesmo modo apenas ao soltar o mouse do botão da classe `input type="range"` que o valor é demostrado para o usuário final.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dê uma olhada a este exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/LuKBm/

Na prática não precisa de jQuery e tem duas opções. Ouvir o evento `input` que muda a cada passo que o mouse mexe, ou ouvir o event `mouseup` que dispara somente quando o mouse levanta.

O código do exemplo é:

```
var p = document.getElementById("price"),
    res1 = document.getElementById("resultado1"),
    res2 = document.getElementById("resultado2");

p.addEventListener("input", function () {
    res1.innerHTML = "€" + p.value;
}, false);
p.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    res2.innerHTML = "€" + p.value;
}, false);
```

Porém se quer usar jQuery, nalguns casos pode ter vantagens, entõ o que precisa é:

```
$('seletorElemento') // um seletor CSS
    .on('mouseup',   // quando ocorrer um mouse up naquele elemento... (pode também usar o "input"
    function(){
        // aqui pode correr o código que precisa, por exemplo mostrar o valor
        $('outroElemento').html(this.value); // no caso de querer mudar o html
    });
```

Sem os comentários:

```
$('#price').on('mouseup', function () {
    $('#resultado1').html(this.value);
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWQX2/)

Comment: ótimo exemplo, funciona muito bem. ai vem mais uma dúvida se por exemplo for necessário inserir um valor decimal contendo números com as devidas virgulas para valores financeiros, tem alguma dica? Obrigado.

Comment: @theflash dê uma olhada nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14729/129

Comment: @theflash: para usar casas decimais pode usar assim: __http://jsfiddle.net/zmW3T/__

Comment: Verifiquei o link enviado @sergio

Comment: @theflash, ok. Isso respondeu à sua pergunta? se não coloque mais informação do que precisa

Comment: é realmente isto onde estava minha dúvida, obrigado pela ajuda!