# JavaScript gerando float com várias casas decimais

Tags: javascript, float

Ao criar um sistema de cálculo de pedidos (quantidade x valor) eu percebi que em alguns casos ao somar valores quebrados o JavaScript retorna números com muitas outras casas decimais a mais que o esperado.

Exemplo:

```
(123*1.23)+(312*3.26) //retorna 1168.4099999999999 ao invés de 1168.41
```

Isto é um comportamento comum no JavaScript? O fato de eu estar calculando valores apenas com duas casas decimais não deveria limitar o resultado tambem a apenas duas casas? Existe alguma forma de fazer o comportamento retornar o valor esperado (ex.: `1168.41`)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sim, isto é um comportamento conhecido no javascript e já [discutido noutras perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14728/129).

Sugestão:

```
var conta = (123*1.23)+(312*3.26);
var arredondado = parseFloat(conta.toFixed(2));

console.log(conta); // 1168.4099999999999 
console.log(arredondado); //1168.41
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p770xhvr/

O [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) arredonda o numero à casa decimal mais próxima e podendo escolher a quantidade de casas decimais. O formato resultante é *string*, daí usar o [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) também.

Comment: Aqui a função não arredonda... pq sér a?

Comment: @DiêgoCorreiadeAndrade o meu exemplo funciona? se não faz um video ou imagem para poder ver o erro?

Comment: Thanks my king =)