# como formatar casas decimais no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, variáveis, float

galera, to com o seguinte codigo aqui, queria saber como faço pra arredondar as casas decimais dos valores flutuantes:
desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar :)

```
           num1 = parseFloat (prompt ("digite o primeiro número para o calculo da média: "));
           num2 = parseFloat (prompt ("digite o segundo número para o calculo da média: "));
           num3 = parseFloat (prompt ("digite o terceiro número para o calculo da média: "));
           var media = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3;
           document.write("<p>média dos valores inseridos: " + (media) + "</p>");
   </script>
```

Comment: media.toFixed(n) onde n é o numero de casas  decimais desejadas

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [JavaScript gerando float com várias casas decimais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29318/javascript-gerando-float-com-v%c3%a1rias-casas-decimais)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basta fazer

```
document.write("<p>média dos valores inseridos: " + (media.toFixed(n)) + "</p>");
```

onde n é o número de casas decimais desejadas.
Segue um link de ajuda: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: O método [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) não arredonda ele trunca

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função Math.floor() caso queira arredondar para baixo ou Math.ceil() para arredondamentos para cima.

Se quiser arredondar a quantidade de casas decimais utilize .toFixed(X), onde o X é a quantidade de casas a arredondar.

```
num1 = parseFloat (prompt ("digite o primeiro número para o calculo da média: "));
num2 = parseFloat (prompt ("digite o segundo número para o calculo da média: "));
num3 = parseFloat (prompt ("digite o terceiro número para o calculo da média: "));
var media = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3;
var mediaArred = Math.floor(media);
document.write("<p>média dos valores inseridos: " + (mediaArred + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, de uma olhada nessa função, resolverá seu problema...

```
Math.round(x);
```

acesse o link abaixo, é a fonte da minha resposta, vai te ajudar!

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round