# Como retornar 2 decimais em um valor monetário com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso tratar esta string para que seja retornado apenas 2 decimais depois do ponto?

```
$(".subtotal2").text(23.90);
    var sum = 0;
    $(".subtotal2").each(function() {

        var val = $.trim( $(this).text() );
        if (val) { val = parseFloat( val.replace( /^\$/, "" ) ); sum += !isNaN( val ) ? val : 0; }

});
$(".todo_total").text(sum*12);
```

> Este código por enquanto me retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Não use `float` pra representar dinheiro em JavaScript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/215), se possível. Use valores inteiros, representando a menor unidade possível (centavos).

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript & também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14728/realiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-contas-de-ponto-flutuante-em-javascript-com-precis%C3%A3o-absoluta

Answer (score 2):

Há ótimas [respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem) sobre o assunto no SO inglês.

Você pode até formatar a sua saída utilizando funções como:

```
toFixed(2);
toPrecision(12);
sprintf("%.2f", number);
round(number, 12);
```

Porém, como o @mgibsonbr já comentou, o melhor a fazer é usar inteiros.

Se quiser consultar por quê isso ocorre, acesse [THE FLOATING-POINT GUIDE](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim amigo:

```
$(".subtotal2").text((23.90).toFixed(2));
$(".todo_total").text((sum*12).toFixed(2));
```