# Comportamento estranho no Javascript

Tags: javascript

> Esta pergunta é mais por curiosidade, já contornei o problema no meu código.

Fiz uma mascara para dinheiro utilizando javascript, ela estava funcionando perfeitamente, até eu entrar com o valor 4.9.

Debugando o código descobri que o problema estava ao multiplicar o valor 4.9 por 100, o resultado desta multiplicação deu:

```
490.00000000000006
```

O que fez com que a minha mascara "bugasse".

Outros valores como 4.8 o resultado é mostrado corretamente, como:

```
480
```

Segue o código abaixo para exemplificar:

```js
alert(4.9*100);

//Sem problemas
alert(4.8*100);

//Outro exemplo mais grave
alert(4.6*100);
```

**A minha pergunta é a seguinte, porque há este estranho comportamento no Javascript? Fiz a mesma multiplicação utilizando php e funcionou normalmente.**

E para quem teve o mesmo problema e quer apenas solucionar, eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

```js
var valor = 4.9;
resultado = (valor  * 100).toFixed(2);
alert(valor);

var valor = 4.6;
resultado = (valor  * 100).toFixed(2);
alert(valor);
```

Comment: Resumidamente, cálculos com números de ponto flutuante não são exatos

Comment: Seria isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14728/realiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-contas-de-ponto-flutuante-em-javascript-com-precis%C3%A3o-absoluta

Comment: esse é um velho conhecido problema de arredondamento de números no javascript, tem essa pergunta interessante no SO em inglês: [how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Isso tem haver com a regulamentação da IEEE para representação binária para número de ponto flutuante. Uma boa saída também é trabalhar com inteiros, multiplicando sua moeda por 100 antes de operar e depois dividir por 100 para ver com os centavos após o ponto.