# Problema ao calcular porcentagem usando parseFloat e toFixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero fazer algo bem simples, mas por mais simples que seja, não estou conseguindo. Eu tenho um input que recebe o valor de custo, um input que calcula e mostra a margem de lucro em % e um input que recebe o preço de venda.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão é a seguinte, do jeito que eu consegui atualmente, o calculo é feito corretamente apenas até o valor (R$ 999,99), quando chega na casa dos milhares, o calculo da um valor errado, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E além de tudo, o calculo ignora as casas decimais. Caso eu coloque um preço de venda sendo R$ 199,00 da a mesma margem de lucro que eu colocar R$ 199,99, ou seja, 199,90 ele enxerga como 199 e 199,00 ele também enxerga como 199. Parece ser algo tão simples e eu não estou conseguindo fazer.

Código que eu tenho atualmente:

```
var precoVenda = parseFloat($("input[name='iptPrcVendaProdutoEditar']").val());             
var precoCusto = parseFloat($("input[name='iptPrcCustoProdutoEditar']").val());
var margemLucro = parseFloat((((precoVenda - precoCusto)/precoCusto)*100)).toFixed(2);
$("input[name='iptMargemLucroProdutoEditar']").val(margemLucro.replace('.',','));
```

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308754/comportamento-estranho-no-javascript, tente utilizar esta lib https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js

Comment: Você precisa remover os pontos e trocar vírgulas por pontos antes de passar parseFloat nos valores dos campos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Também podem ser usados `split` e `join` para converter os campos.

Coloquei snippet para exemplificar.

```js
function calculo() {

var pv = parseFloat($("input[name='iptPrcVendaProdutoEditar']").val().split('.').join('').split(',').join('.'));

var pc = parseFloat($("input[name='iptPrcCustoProdutoEditar']").val().split('.').join('').split(',').join('.'));

$("input[name='iptMargemLucroProdutoEditar']").val(

(!isNaN(pv) && !isNaN(pc) ?

((pv - pc) / pc * 100).toFixed(2) + '%' :

'')

);

};

$('input').not(':last').on('keyup', function() { calculo(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Preço venda: <input type="text" name="iptPrcVendaProdutoEditar" /><br /><br />
Preço custo: <input type="text" name="iptPrcCustoProdutoEditar" /><br /><br />
Margem lucro: <input type="text" name="iptMargemLucroProdutoEditar" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 1):

função para trocar caracteres

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

como chamar função

```
replaceAll('20,00',',','.');
```

outra forma simples

```
variavel.replace(/,/g, '.');
```

Comment: Resolveu 50% do problema @Willian, agora o calculo é feito corretamente até R$ 999,99 e com os valores corretos das casas decimais, porém quando eu coloco um preço de custo sendo R$ 100,00 e um preço de venda sendo R$ 1000,00 ele calcula -99,00% de margem de lucro.

Comment: https://ideone.com/leEW4R @J.Thatcher ae como eu fiz... seguinte o erro ta no . do 1.000,00 e so remover ele, ponhe um replace '.','' para seus valores de entrada

Comment: se der erro na margen de lucro passa pra string, depois remove o uqe precisa e volta pra float