# Soma de valores decimais em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ao fazer somas de valores decimais em Javascript (no exemplo com duas casas decimais). Algumas vezes a soma gera um resultado com 'n' casas decimais a mais outras vezes não.

A dúvida é:

Porque isso acontece?

Como padronizar o resultado da forma que você deseja.

Exemplo.

```js
document.getElementById("exemplo").innerHTML = 1.25+1.36
document.getElementById("exemplo2").innerHTML = 1.25+1.37
```

```html
<div id="exemplo"></div>
<div id="exemplo2"></div>
```

Comment: Use o [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para arrendondar e leie esta pergunta: [Realização de contas de ponto flutuante em JavaScript com precisão absoluta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14728/realiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-contas-de-ponto-flutuante-em-javascript-com-precis%c3%a3o-absoluta)

Comment: acima como no comentário acima, de uma pesquisada sobre funções matematicas em js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o Math para arredondar o resulado, ou simplesmente fazer a conversão para float.

```js
Math.floor(1.25+1.36) //Resultado 2 , Valor arrendado para baixo

Math.ceil(1.25+1.36) //Resultado 3 , Valor arrendado para cima

parseFloat(1.25+1.37) //Resultado 2.62
```

Answer (score -1):

é bem simples de resolver

use o `parseFloat()`

```js
document.getElementById("exemplo").innerHTML = parseFloat(1.25+1.37)
document.getElementById("exemplo2").innerHTML = parseFloat(1.25) + parseFloat(1.37)
```

```html
<div id="exemplo"></div>
<div id="exemplo2"></div>
```