# Por que (!+[]+[]+![]).length retorna 9 em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Acabei de ler [esse artigo](http://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/javascript_the_weird_parts) e nele há esta expressão:

```
(!+[]+[]+![]).length
```

Avaliando isso no interpretador:

```
> (!+[]+[]+![]).length
9
```

Bom, por que?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Passo a passo:

```
+[] === 0
!+[] === true
!+[]+[] === "true"
(!+[]+[])+![] === (!+[]+[])+false === "truefalse"
"truefalse".length === 9
```

Tem diversas coerções de tipo que no final causam esse resultado. Detalhando a primeira linha acima:

```
+[] ⟶ +"" ⟶ 0
```

Portanto temos:

```
!+[] ⟶ !0 ⟶ !false ⟶ true
```

Seguindo em frente:

```
!+[]+[] ⟶ true + [] ⟶ true + "" ⟶ "true"
```

Esse `"true"` será concatenado com:

```
![]  ⟶ !true ⟶ false
```

Portanto:

```
"true" + false ⟶ "truefalse"
```

### Referências relevantes da especificação:

- [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2)
- [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)
- [Array.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2)
- [Unary + Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6)
- [Addition Operator (+)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)

---

#### Sobre o [artigo](http://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/javascript_the_weird_parts) que você citou

Li o artigo e fiquei decepcionado. Tudo bem que já virou chavão dizer que *JS sucks*, [*à la* wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat), mas tem umas críticas injustas. Então vou listar alguns pontos aqui em defesa da linguagem:

- Ao tentar fazer comparações entre certos tipos (como array e object), a linguagem poderia mesmo lançar uma exceção. Mas pra mim o verdadeiro WTF é o programador fazer algo como `{} > []` ou `![]` e esperar uma resposta que faça sentido... A linguagem optou por *type coercion*, e [as regras disso](https://262.ecma-international.org/8.0/#sec-type-conversion) são necessariamente arbitrárias.
- Não é estranho que [o tipo de `NaN` seja number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2801601), já que `NaN` é definido no standard de aritmética de números de ponto flutuante ([IEEE 754](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/112052))
- `"string" instanceof String === false` porque [existe uma diferença entre o valores primitivos do tipo string e objetos do tipo String](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75699/112052). Em Java é parecido, não?
- Reclamar que `0.1+0.2!==0.3` é desconhecimento básico de [aritmética de ponto flutuante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/112052) em praticamente qualquer linguagem.
- Reclamar que `Math.max()<Math.min()` é não ter lido nenhuma documentação sobre esses métodos. O objetivo deles não é retornar os valores máximo e mínimo entendidos pela linguagem, e sim entre os passados. Se você não passa nada, `max` retorna `-Infinity`, o que faz algum sentido.

Poderia dizer mais, mas vou parar por aqui...

Comment: JS e bizarro XP

Comment: É que o mecanismo de coerção de tipos não é muito intuitivo, especialmente quando tentamos fazer coisas como usar `+` entre arrays. A linguagem não prevê nenhuma operação especial para isso (como união dos conjuntos representados nas arrays), por isso há conversão.

Comment: Alem de poder fazer `! + []` o que e MUITO estranho.

Comment: @LucasVirgili Mas atenção que o `!+[]` do começo é na verdade `!(+[])` (ou seja, há uma coerção de array para número, depois desse número para booleano).

Comment: Eu entendi, @bfavaretto. Ainda acho que e algo que deveria ser um erro de sintaxe XD

Comment: Também acho, @LucasVirgili Não faz nenhum sentido converter array pra número, negar array, etc.

Comment: Eu queria poder favoritar respostas, favoritaria esta.

Comment: @LucasVirgili Atualizei minha resposta rebatendo alguns pontos do artigo que você citou.

Comment: Não tem como fazer  `+[]` ser um erro de sintaxe, já que `+` é um operador unário que aceita qualquer expressão. O melhor que você poderia fazer é gerar um erro de tipo, que em Javascript surgiria como uma exceção em tempo de execução.

Comment: @hugomg Verdade, mas acho que foi isso que o Lucas quis dizer, lançar uma exceção de algum tipo.

Comment: A maior parte do que o cara fala de fato é muito mais "wat" pois não deveria ser tentada mesmo, @bfvaretto. Quem lá sou eu para falar que alguma linguagem tem um design ruim quando as que eu fiz eram nojentas :P

Comment: Recomendado: [*JavaScript: The Lingua Franca of the Web*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/javascript-the-lingua-franca-of-the-web/)

Comment: Dessas esquisitices do JS, minha favorita é `Array(16).join("lol" - 2) + " Batman!"`. Nem precisa rodar pra saber o que vai sair daí. :D

Comment: Sim, alguém fazer `{} > []` literalmente seria muito esquisito. Mas isso é só pra efeito de visibilidade, pois na prática as pessoas testam duas variáveis que podem conter qualquer coisa. Logo, apesar de ser extremamente improvável alguém fazer o teste literal, as expressões são muito comuns quando usamos variáveis principalmente parâmetros de entrada em métodos.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, gostei do `"NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN Batman!"`. Isso soa como música aos ouvidos :)