# Por que no JavaScript, o 7 (um número) não é uma instância de Number?

Tags: javascript

Quando fazemos o seguinte teste abaixo, é retornado `false`.

```
console.log(7 instanceof Number); // FALSE
```

Porém, no segundo teste, é retornado `true`.

```
var number = new Number('3');

console.log(number instanceof Number) // TRUE
```

Em um segundo cenário, temos também uma variação quando utilizamos `typeof`:

```
typeof 1 // "number"

typeof new Number(1) // "object"
```

Não entendo o por quê disso, já que, nos exemplos abaixo, tanto o `object` como o `number` possuirão o método criado em `Number` através do `prototype`!

Veja:

```
Number.prototype.square = function ()
{
   return Math.pow(this, 2);
}

var x = 3;

x.square(); // 9

new Number(3).square() // 9

(3).square() // 9
```

Alguém sabe por que ocorre essa <del>doidice</del> variação?

Comment: Talvez porque o 7(ou qualquer outro número) é tratado como uma string quando não é declarado?

Comment: Desculpe agora entendi melhor, vou terminar a resposta e já posto

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, `typeof 7 = 'number'`. `typeof '7' = 'string'`

Comment: Não é só o 7 que não é uma instância de Number.. Seu título ainda está meio _misleading_

Comment: Quando alguém dar um -1, poderia pelo menos explicar , para ver o que posso melhorar na minha pergunta

Comment: precisa instanciar explicitamente...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tomei -2 e ninguém me explicou também, mas no dia que estou passando hoje... o que menos me preocupa é os negativos daqui

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Em JavaScript, existem *tipos primitivos* para *String*, *Number* e *Boolean* (além de *Object* e dos tipos *Null* e *Undefined*, que só têm uma instância cada). Então, valores primitivos como os do exemplo abaixo não são objetos:

```
var texto = "Texto";
var numero = 7;
var booleano = true;

texto instanceof String;     // false
numero instanceof Number;    // false
booleano instanceof Boolean; // false
```

O [operador `instanceof`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-instanceofoperator) não diz o tipo do valor. Se o valor for um objeto, o `instanceof` diz se o que está do lado direito é um dos itens da [cadeia de protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15247/74) desse objeto – e por isso `new Number(7) instanceof Number === true`, já que o número foi criado com o construtor `Number`.

O que dá o tipo do valor é o operador `typeof`, com o qual você obtém o tipo dos primitivos:

```
typeof texto;     // "string"
typeof numero;    // "number"
typeof booleano;  // "boolean"
```

Quando você tenta acessar uma propriedade, o engine sabe como ["embrulhar"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getv) o valor num objeto do tipo correspondente (`String`, `Number` ou `Boolean`), para em seguida retornar a propriedade. Isso é semelhante ao *autoboxing* do Java. O objeto criado é temporário, ele não existe como variável após a obtenção do valor da propriedade (embora os engines possam fazer otimizações e mantê-lo na memória se acharem necessário). É assim que funcionam expressões do tipo:

```
"foo".length;
(7).toFixed();
7..toFixed(); // o primeiro ponto é o separador de casas decimais
true.valueOf();
```

Comment: Então, apesar de `7` ser do tipo `Number`, ele usa o objeto `Number`, porém não é uma instância do mesmo :\

Comment: Não é bem isso. Os tipos em JS são String, Number, Boolean, Null, Undefined e Object. O construtor `Number` (como em `var n = new Number(1)`) cria uma instância de um objeto. O `instanceof` diz quem é o construtor (ou um ancestral dele na cadeia de protótipo). O tipo de `n` é objeto. O tipo de `n.valueOf()` é número. Ficou mais claro?

Comment: Agora entendi! É que, no `python` por exemplo, `isinstance(1, int)` retorna `True`! Eu esperava que no `javascript` fosse a mesma coisa!

Comment: Eu não sei muito de Python, mas isso indica que talvez lá tudo seja objeto. Em JS não é assim.

Comment: Então o JS possue os tipos primitivos, que não são objetos, mas quando acessados, são transformados em objetos, mas ainda sim não são objetos. É isso mesmo? Por que toda essa confusão, por que não apenas fazer tudos ser objetos (incluindo os primitivos)

Answer (score 6):

`Strings` e `Numbers` são valores primitivos, e não objetos e, portanto, não possuem um `[[Prototype]]`, por isso só vai funcionar se você instanciá-los como objetos.

O mesmo problema ocorreria no caso:

```
console.log("Texto" instanceof String); -> false

var texto = new String('3');
console.log(texto instanceof String) -> true
```

Tem uma referencia muito explicativa e boa [aqui no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/472427/3956218)

Comment: Mas como explicar que `(7).toFixed(3)` funcione, já que os mesmos são valores primitivos? É isso que eu queria entender no javascript. Porque tanto `new Number(3).toFixed()` e `(3).toFixed()` funciona?

Comment: (x) não seria um cast implicito?

Comment: Aí teria que provar que `7 !== (7)`. Porque pra mim retornou `true` para `(7) === 7` e `false` para `new Number(7) === 7`

Comment: @Dener `(x)` é só uma expressão com parênteses para organizar precedência, `(x) === x`.

Comment: Ah sim. Então ai fica minha dúvida também o por quê do `x.toFixed()` dar erro e o `(x).toFixed()` não, realmente achei que estava fazendo um `cast` implícito nele pra não dar erro.

Answer (score 4):

Simplesmente porque ele "não é" uma [instancia de objeto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505405/javascript-creating-new-instance-of-objects).

Instancias de objetas são declaradas utilizando a [*keyword* `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript).

O problema relatado também ocorre para as seguinte situações:

```
"string" instanceof String;      // false
true     instanceof Boolean;     // false
```

O curioso é que não ocorre o mesmo para os tipos *array* e *object*:

```
({foo: "bar"}) instanceof Object;  // true
[1,2,3] instanceof Array;          // true
```

Isso ocorre porque objetos realmente [são Objetos no javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp), já o caso do *array* é ainda mais peculiar, pois no Javascript *arrays* são objetos, tanto que a seguinte expressão é verdadeira:

```
[1,2,3] instanceof Object; // true
typeof [1,2,3];            // object
```

O Javascript não é (era) uma linguagem orientada a objetos, mas sim uma linguagem orientada a protótipos (ou protótipos de objetos). Na MDN lê-se o seguinte:

> Em Javascript a herança ocorre por meio de objetos protótipos<sup>[4](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt/Javascript_orientado_a_objetos#jsoop4)</sup> e define uma relação do tipo “é um” (“is a” relationship). Cada objeto herda propriedades e métodos de seu objeto protótipo que é referenciado pela propriedade prototype. [MDN: Javascript orientado a objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Javascript_orientado_a_objetos#Heran.C3.A7a)

Ou seja, no teu exemplo:

```
Number.prototype.square = function ()
{
   return Math.pow(this, 2);
}
```

Você está adicionando um método ao protótipo do objeto `Number`, ou seja, não apenas os objetos `Number`'s vão herdar esse método, como também qualquer "objeto" (tipagens e etc) que também herdam o protótipo `Number`.

Alguns links sobre:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505405/javascript-creating-new-instance-of-objects
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Javascript_orientado_a_objetos

Comment: Então, talvez isso seja mais um erro do que "ter uma explicação", já que em arrays funciona. E exatamente por isso fiz a pergunta: No javascript, tudo é objeto!

Comment: Mas por que é que todos meus últimos exemplos "herdaram" `.square`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters complementei a resposta para tua dúvida.

Comment: Obrigado pela boa vontade de todos :)