# Todos os valores de JavaScript, exceto primitivos, são objetos?

Tags: javascript, tipagem, objetos

A documentação na w3school fala que Todos os valores de JavaScript, exceto primitivos, são objetos, que são eles:

```
string
number
boolean
null
undefined
```

Então

```
let nome = 'João';
```

É do tipo primitivo string, e por que eu consigo acessar métodos ?

```
console.log(typeof nome); //retorna o tipo string
```

Comment: No [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) está escrito > Praticamente todos os objetos em JavaScript descendem de Object; todos os métodos e propriedades herdados de Object.prototype, embora possam ser sobrescritos (exceto um Objeto com protótipo nulo, i.e. Object.create(null)). Por exemplo, outros protótipos construtores sobrescrevem a propriedade construtora e fornece seus próprios toString() métodos.

Comment: Então minha variável é do tipo primitivo string, que string é um objeto então por isso eu posso acessar os métodos do obj string ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

W3Schools nunca foi algo confiável (embora dizem ter melhorado com o tempo) e a especificação usa termos universalmente errados. Um dos erros é achar que existem coisas que são objetos e outras que não são. [Tudo é objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101). Existem objetos por referência e por valor e pode ser que aí tenha um diferenciação. Talvez que o que eles falem que sejam objetos é o que vem de `Object`.

[O conceito de primitivo não é muito bem concebido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type), alguns entendem que são objetos que o processador entende, por isso só os tipos numéricos básicos, o que pode incluir um só caractere simples (JS não tem esse tipo de dado) seriam primitivos. A ideia é que o dado é rudimentar, portanto muito simples.

Outra definição é que a linguagem dá tratamento especial para o tipo (seria *builtin*) e por isso ele seria um primitivo, no sentido de original.

Na especificação da EcmaScript inventaram um significado próprio para o termo e escolheram a dedo o que vão chamar de primitivo e o que vão chamar de "objeto". Só quem escreveu isso sabe porque cada tipo é uma coisa ou outra, mas parece, à primeira vista, que segue a linha de ter tratamento especial da linguagem e portanto `Object` (que também tem um tratamento especial, é *builtin*, mas por alguma razão eles acharam que não deveria ser considerado primitivo) e os tipos criados pelo programador não são primitivos. E por alguma razão um *array* é considerado como um `Object` e não recebe discriminação, e ele tem tratamento especial.

> A primitive value is a datum that is represented directly at the lowest level of the language implementation

Isto está na especificação e não quer dizer nada sozinho, precisaria de mais explicação do que é "o nível mais baixo da implementação da linguagem", o que parece ser a primeira definição que eu dei, mas aí `String` está errado, provavelmente `Null` e `Undefined` também, por isso tentar achar uma lógica na definição não vai chegar a algum lugar.

Ou talvez quiseram considerar que tipos por valor fossem primitivos, e `String` foi considerado assim por ter semântica por valor mesmo que seja um tipo por referência. Talvez isso explique a exceção que está achando que tem.

Cometeram o mesmo erro que Java cometeu, seria muito melhor que tudo fosse um `Object`, ainda que alguns tipos fossem por valor.

Na verdade se está achando algo errado deveria justificar o porquê de achar isto. Se a linguagem decidiu ser assim por alguma razão, para o contexto dela está certo e não cabe contestação. Pode caber explicação, mas lembremos que esta linguagem começou com um nome, depois mudou ([EcmaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/)) para ser padronizada e só então foi criada uma especificação em cima de algo já implementado de forma atropelada em tempo recorde, por isso muita coisa saiu torta, então temos que aceitar que é assim, só isso.

Mas lendo a especificação mais um pouco começam falar de outras definições do que parece a mesma coisa, não é fácil entender. Já vi implementadores de JS dizerem que tem muita ambiguidade na especificação e é difícil tomar decisão, e por isso tem implementações que fazem coisas diferentes, cada um entendeu de um jeito.

Portanto a pergunta nem faz muito sentido. Um tipo `string` é um objeto, que por uma definição é um primitivo, em outra não é, portanto é irrelevante essa diferença, e objetos podem ter métodos.

Não é só `String` que pode acessar métodos, outros primitivos também podem, só não são os mesmos métodos, ter métodos não é algo exclusivo de um tipo de dado, só isso pode ser tomado como verdade. Veja:

```js
console.log(12..toFixed(2));
console.log(true.valueOf());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/Primitives.js).

Ou seja, é tudo muito confuso porque é mal definido. Se quiser ver começa na [seção 4.2 da especificação atual](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-overview).

Comment: Estava achando que era dup de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75676, mas depois desta resposta não sei mais, mudou minha leitura da pergunta.

Comment: É parecida mas acho que o foco é outro, é mais sobre existir métodos nos tipos "primitivos", por isso achei que deveria tentar achar uma explicação maior para a confusão do AP, boa parte da resposta é porque gosto de ir além do "é assim e boa" que é o penúltimo parágrafo. Acho que uma complementa bem a outra, vou tentar melhorar porque acho importante. Vou melhorar ainda, porque sempre que releio lembro de algo mais ou posso tornar o texto mais claro.