# Por que (1 == true) é "verdadeiro" e (2 == true) é "falso"?

Tags: javascript, operadores, conversão-de-tipo

Eu estava explicando para um amigo meu a diferença entre `==` e `===` no PHP e quis demonstrar isso através do console do javascript.

Ia demonstrar a ele que, no PHP, as sentenças abaixo retornariam `TRUE` quando usado o operador de comparação `==`.

Assim:

```
var_dump(1 == true); // TRUE

var_dump(2 == true); // TRUE
```

Porém, ao aplicar isso no console para exemplificar com o javascript, o resultado foi esse:

```
test1 = 1 == true;

test2 = 2 == true;

console.log(test1); // true
console.log(test2); // false
```

## Atualização

Quando fazemos a instância de `Boolean` com esses números, os resultados são diferentes:

```
new Boolean(1); // true
new Boolean(2); // true
new Boolean(0); // false
```

Comment: Perguntas banacas sobre js :), [Operador == e === em JavaScript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/91) e 
[Por que (!+\[\]+\[\]+!\[\]).length retorna 9 em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30880/91)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É uma decisão de cada linguagem determinar quais valores são considerados verdadeiro ou falso e obrigação do programador de cada uma delas saber qual é o padrão adotado pela linguagem que está usando.

O mais comum é que as linguagens decidam que falso são os valores "neutros", como o zero, e verdadeiro é qualquer outro valor que não o neutro.

Há de se notar que algumas linguagens dão valores numéricos para `true` (1) e para `false` (0), mas não é o caso do JS.

Por outro lado existem linguagens que sequer é possível fazer esta comparação já que os tipos dos dados são diferentes. Linguagens de tipagem verdadeiramente forte não tem esse problema, `false` é `false` e `true` é `true`, não tem confusão alguma. Em linguagens de tipagem fraca é possível fazer alguns tipos se passarem por falso ou verdadeiro.

JavaScript é assim. Mas vamos lembrar que também é uma linguagem que tenta fazer conversões automáticas. E a conversão de `true` é feita para 1. Assim como a conversão de `false` é feita para 0.

Então, neste caso, a comparação é feita para o valor numérico e obviamente 2 é diferente de 1. Se `true` vale `1` a comparação ficaria assim:

```
2 == 1
```

Lembrando que o ideal é sempre fazer a comparação usado o operador `===`, assim o tipo é levado em consideração e evita este tipo de problema. Neste caso a comparação de tipos diferentes sempre será considerado `false`. O operador `==` deveria apenas ser usado para fazer coisas engraçadinhas. Mesmo que realmente não queira levar em consideração o tipo, deveria fazer a conversão do tipo explicitamente, ainda que a linguagem faria o desejado automaticamente. Ser explícito é sempre mais interessante em casos assim.

O ideal é nem ter tipagem fraca, mas mesmo que tenha só uma precedência de coerção de tipos em cada contexto para o que o programador espera já faria a linguagem ser muito melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 17):

O que acontece é o seguinte, quando o `true` é substituído por um valor numérico, ele assume o valor de 1, por isso quando você faz:

```
1 == true
```

Na verdade você está fazendo:

```
1 == 1
```

O que retornará `true`, já no segundo caso, o que acontecerá será:

```
2 == 1
```

O que, naturalmente, retornará `false`. Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados [nessa resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23693276/1606920).

Answer (score 2):

Se não me engano no Javascript o teste de igualdade com dois iguais (`==`) ele converte os valores de comparação para o nível mais próximo.

Logo `1 == true`, ele converte true para 1
Logo `0 == false`, ele converte false para 0

Logo 2 == true ou 2 == 1 é false

Ainda assim existe dois tipos de comparação com sinal de igual no javascript

`==` (x == y)
`===` (x == y e o tipo de `x` é o mesmo tipo de `y`)

Espero ter ajudado.

Fonte: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: O que ocorre na verdade é que o true é convertido para 1 e o false para 0. 2 == true, correponde a dizer 2 == 1. Veja respostas anteriores