# Se Boolean('0') é true e Boolean(0) é false, porque '0' == false é true em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Por que em javascript  `Boolean('0')` é `true`, `Boolean(0)` é false, sendo que, ao comparar `'0'` (um zero sozinho na string) com `false` ele retorna `true`?

Por que desse comportamento?

Exemplo:

```js
console.log(Boolean('0'));
console.log(Boolean(0));

console.log('0' == false);


console.log(Boolean('1'));
console.log(Boolean(1));
```

Se eu converto `'0'` para `Boolean` é `true`, mas se comparo com `false` é verdadeiro?  Qual é o motivo nisso?

<sub>Não tente entender, apenas aceite! Isso mostra que você confia na linguagem :D</sub>

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que 1 == true é “verdadeiro” e 2 == true é “falso”?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77051/91)

Comment: @rray obrigado. Eu não consegui achar ela.  Parece que caracteres como `=` e afins dificultam a localização das perguntas, hehehe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A razão de o comportamento ser diferente tem a ver com quais as conversões de tipos a serem feitas.

Quando tens `Boolean('0')` é o mesmo que `Boolean('x')` pois aos olhos do *Tipo Boolean* é uma string com conteúdo. Ou seja neste caso o responsável pela conversão é o `Boolean()`.

Quando tens um comparador `==` aí as regras são diferentes. Podes [ler na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) o seguinte:

> **Equal (==)**
>
> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands >then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible;

Ou seja, o JavaScript converte ambos os valores em numero perante um comparador onde um dos membros da comparação é um booleano.

Então a comparação é entre `Number('0')` e `Number(false)` que são os dois `0`.

Pode ler-se sobre a lógica de comparação também diretamente na [especificação da ECMASrcript aqui](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), e neste caso (no segundo exemplo) cai primeiro no caso `7`, e depois no caso `5`.

> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
> return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.