# Quando "x >= y" e "x <= y" não se comportam como "x > y || x == y" e "x < y || x == y"?

Tags: javascript, operadores, null

Como o `null` pode ser maior ou igual a `0` **e** menor ou igual a `0` ao mesmo tempo em que não é igual, menor e nem maior que `0`?

```js
console.log(null >= 0); //true
console.log(null <= 0); //true
console.log(null == 0); //false
console.log(null > 0);  //false
console.log(null < 0);  //false
```

Comment: Veja a "mágica" acontecer executando: `+null `...

Comment: vale a leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77051/por-que-1-true-%c3%a9-verdadeiro-e-2-true-%c3%a9-falso/77057#77057 - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154169/se-boolean0-%c3%a9-true-e-boolean0-%c3%a9-false-porque-0-false-%c3%a9-true-em-javas?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: É um ótimo exemplo pra adicionar na lista dos porquês que fazem o JavaScript ser uma linguagem ruim :P

Comment: Alterei o titulo, porque o problema não é exatamente sobre NULL, mas sobre o comportamento de `x >= y` e `x <= y` ser diferente de `x > y || x == y` e `x < y || x == y` em **alguns casos**. @Matheus se você discordar da edição você ainda pode [edit] ou [reverter a edição](/posts/593268/revisions).

Answer (score 5):

Este comportamento está bem descrito na documentação de cada operador. Seguem os links abaixo para referência:

| Operador | Link documentação |
| --- | --- |
| `==` | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality |
| `<` | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than |
| `>` | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than |
| `<=` | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than_or_equal |
| `>=` | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than_or_equal |

E vale ler também a [especificação oficial da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-relational-operators) para uma explicação mais detalhada (embora bem mais complexa de entender).

---

Cada link acima tem a explicação do que acontece quando um dos operandos é `null`. Mas de forma geral, temos dois casos principais: o `==` e os demais.

No caso do `==`, o algoritmo usa a operação `IsLooselyEqual`, [descrita na especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-islooselyequal). De forma resumida, uma das condições diz que se um dos operandos é `null`, o operador só retorna `true` se o outro operando for `null` ou `undefined`. Por isso que comparar `null` com zero (ou qualquer outro valor) resulta em `false`.

---

Já os demais operadores usam a operação `IsLessThan` para comparar os valores. [O algoritmo é bem complexo](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-islessthan), mas um dos casos - conforme [descrito na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than#description) - diz que se um dos operandos for `null`, este é convertido para `0`. Por isso que `null < 0` é `false`, pois no fim é feita a comparação `0 < 0`. Isso tem como consequência que `0 < null` também é `false`.

O operador `>` usa este mesmo algoritmo, apenas invertendo a ordem dos operandos - ou seja, `x > y` equivale a `y < x`. E como `0 < null` é `false`, então `null > 0` também é.

---

Mas se `null` não é igual a zero e também não é maior e nem menor que zero, então por que ele é menor ou igual **e** maior ou igual a zero?

Basicamente "porque sim". A documentação do operador `<=` diz o seguinte:

> *When one of `x` or `y` is `null`, and the other is something that's not `null` and becomes `0` when coerced to numeric (including `0`, `0n`, `false`, `""`, `"0"`, `new Date(0)`, etc.): `x <= y` is `true`*

Ou seja, se um dos operandos é `null` e o outro não é, mas quando convertido para número resulta em zero, o resultado é `true`. E `null <= 0` cai neste caso: um dos operandos é `null` e o outro não, e este quando convertido para número resulta em zero (neste caso nem precisa converter, pois já é o próprio zero). Por isso que o resultado é `true`. A mesma regra vale para o operador `>=`.

E por que é assim? A resposta pode ser frustrante, mas basicamente é porque decidiram que seria assim. Cada linguagem define seus operadores da forma que bem entender, faça sentido ou não. Em algumas, por exemplo, o código nem compila se tentar comparar `null` com um número. Mas em JavaScript decidiram que `null >= 0` e `null <= 0` retornam `true`, mesmo que `null == 0`, `null < 0` e `null > 0` retornem `false`. [A linguagem é cheia dessas inconsistências e maluquices](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat), então minha sugestão é testar se os operandos possuem valores válidos antes de fazer qualquer operação com eles (a menos que você saiba o que está fazendo, claro).

Vale lembrar que todos esses comportamentos estranhos foram decisões arbitrárias, e não importa muito se eu ou você ou qualquer outra pessoa achar que não faz sentido. É assim porque definiram que é assim e pronto.

Comment: +1, por citar a documentação e por descrever de forma clara, um bom conteudo para o site.

Comment: +1, boa resposta, talvez seja válido citar como resolver o problema convertendo os dados antes de comparar ou usando `===`, conforme a necessidade.

Comment: @Benilson nesse caso pode referenciar as boas respostas que já existem no site, porque o problema da pergunta não é sobre ==, é sobre `x >= y` se comportar diferente de `x == y || x > y` em alguns casos específicos, então citar o === não teria relação, por isso no máximo referenciar como extra, mas não como relacionado. PS: Inclusive estou pensando em mudar o titulo da pergunta atual, para ficar claro que a dúvida é sobre o comportamento dos operadores similares, mas vou esperar a opinião da comunidade.