# Por que no javascript "{} + []" é igual a 0?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Eu estava assistindo um vídeo que me foi mostrado pelo usuário `@CiganoMorrisonMendez`, chamado [WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Lá tinha uns exemplos onde mostravam algumas coisas bizarras presentes em algumas linguagens.

Em particular o que me chamou a atenção foi essa linha de JavaScript:

```
{} + [] // Resultado: 0
```

Ao somar um `objeto` com um `array` o valor `0` é retornado. Pode até parecer sem noção isso, mas quero saber a explicação para isso, já que para essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30880/por-que-length-retorna-9-em-javascript) também existe uma explicação para a esquisitice.

Qual é o motivo desse comportamento? Gostaria de uma explicação passo a passo igual o da pergunta supracitada.

Comment: Vazio = Falso, Falso = 0, 0 + 0 = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esses exemplos que geram curiosidade têm a vêr com a maneira com o JavaScript usa a adição entre Tipos diferentes. Ninguem se espanta que `1 + 2` seja `3`. Mas se perguntamos `3 + '4'` já nem todos terão a certeza que JavaScript sabe adicionar Numeros e Strings.

O que acontece com `{} + []` é que JavaScript tenta converter os tipos para tentar resolver o problema. O que ele faz é ler `{}` ele ignora por ser um [bloco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) vazio, e depois vai tentar converter `[]` num número. O `+` em JavaScript pode ser usado como conversor de Tipo para número, usa-de muito em `+Date` por exemplo para converter a data no timestamp ou `+'10` que dá um Numero, 10. Ou seja `+[]` é a conversão de `[]` em Numero, o mesmo que `Number([]);`  que é `0`.

Há um [bom artigo sobre isso aqui](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html), com este exemplo e outros que tais. Enfim, casos que raramente se usam mas que podem ser engraçados de conhecer.

Comment: Interessante a última explicação sobre `Number([])`, pois notei que o mesmo acontece com o operador `-` (subtração)

Comment: Conforme artigo citado, ele utiliza exemplos via console.log, porém deveria ser rodado direto no V8, ou utilizar a função `eval({}+[])` nesse caso retorna 0, porém se fizer `{}+{}` retorna "[object Object][object Object]" e com `eval('{}+{}');` retorna `NaN`

Comment: @David pois no Node.js dá alguns resultados diferentes que na implementação dos browsers/consola.