# Porque isNaN(true) retorna 'false'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Galera, estava estudando porém não entendi, porque o isNaN(true) é 'false', se true não é um número? (Sou Iniciante!)

Comment: A pergunta refere-se a alguma linguagem específica ou no geral?

Comment: geral, mas pode ser melhor em js (caso tenha diferenças dependendo da linguagem)

Comment: Implementações são específicas às linguagens ou frameworks. JS, por sinal, é bem conhecido pela sua incoerência. Quanto à pergunta, é melhor edita-la para deixar claro o que vc quer saber e editar as tags de acordo.

Comment: há inúmeros apresentações sobre JS, como essa: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE8tL8NdHaY

Comment: Como `isNaN` não existe em Python, acho melhor limitar a pergunta a JS - em Python existe algo similar no módulo `math`, mas misturar linguagens na mesma pergunta deixaria ela ampla. Se quiser saber sobre Python, sugiro fazer outra pergunta específica.

Comment: Entendo, Obrigado pelas dicas sobre as perguntas, eu tinha essa conta aqui mas não tinha usado antes, realmente to aqui para aprender.

Comment: Ações incoerentes? JavaScript incoerente. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30884/69296

Comment: E por falar de JavaScript incoerente: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Mais aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et8xNAc2ic8 , repositório da palestra: https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs

Answer (score 1):

Veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#return_value):

> *true if the given value is NaN; otherwise, false.*

Ou seja, retorna `true` se o valor for [a propriedade global `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), senão (para qualquer outra coisa que não seja `NaN`) retorna `false`.

Claro, isso em linhas gerais. Pois o comportamento de `isNaN` para argumentos não-numéricos é mais confuso que isso.

Se você passa algo que não é um número, primeiro é feita uma coerção para `Number`, e depois verificado se o resultado é `NaN`.

Isso é confuso por causa do nome da propriedade `NaN`: "not a number" pode dar a entender que qualquer coisa que não seja um número (como o valor `true`, strings, outros objetos) seja um `NaN`, mas na verdade somente quando a coerção para `Number` resultar em `NaN` é que a função retorna `true`.

Um exemplo é a string vazia, que quando convertida para `Number`, resulta em zero (e portanto, `isNaN` retorna `false`):

```js
console.log(Number('')); // 0
console.log(isNaN('')); // false
```

Algo similar ocorre com `true`, pois ao convertê-lo para `Number`, resulta em `1`:

```js
console.log(Number(true)); // 1
console.log(isNaN(true)); // false
```

Mas se eu passar uma string como 'abc', `isNaN` retorna `true`, pois a conversão desta string para `Number` retorna `NaN`:

```js
console.log(Number('abc')); // NaN
console.log(isNaN('abc')); // true
```

E para deixar mais confuso ainda:

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log(Number(d)); // 1612194374804 (o valor varia pois corresponde à data atual)
console.log(isNaN(d)); // false

console.log(Number(d.toString())); // NaN
console.log(isNaN(d.toString())); // true
```

Pois um `Date` pode ser diretamente convertido para `Number`, mas a string retornada `toString()` não.

---

O algoritmo completo está na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number), e é o que já foi dito:

1. Let `num` be `ToNumber(number)`.
2. If `num` is `NaN`, return `true`.
3. Otherwise, return `false`.

E o algoritmo da operação `ToNumber` é explicado [aqui](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber).

Answer (score -3):

isNaN = Isso nao e um numero? voce afirmando com true, significa que isNaN ou seja, ele nao e um numero.

```
isNaN(1) = false
isNaN(true) = false
```