# problemas a incrementar casa decimal dentro de loop for

Tags: javascript, loop

```
var iniciaEm = 0;
var terminaEm = 20;
var variacao = 0.1;
var s = "";
var str = "";
for(var i =iniciaEm; i<=terminaEm; i=i+variacao){
     str += i; 
    s += "<option value=\""+i+"%\">"+i+"%</option>";
}

$("#teste").append(s);

// retorno:
    0
    0.1
    0.2
    0.30000000000000004
    0.4
    0.5
    0.6
    0.7
    0.7999999999999999
    0.8999999999999999
    0.9999999999999999
    1.0999999999999999
```

gostaria que os valores variasse a cada `0,1`, qual o problema do meu código?

segue o jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7wx1t5yb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O JavaSript tem problemas com cálculos e imprecisões numéricas conhecidas. Há uma pergunta e [muitas respostas boas sobre isso aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/129)

Na prática para o teu problema podes fazer assim:

```
var nr = i.toFixed(1);
```

dessa maneira limitas a "cauda" do número a décimos.

O código poderia ser assim:

```
for (var i = iniciaEm; i <= terminaEm; i = i + variacao) {
    var nr = i.toFixed(1);
    str += nr + "<br />";
    s += "<option value=\"" + nr + "%\">" + nr + "%</option>";
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7x2hqnhm/

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo correto, o problema é com a falta de precisão ao lidar com pontos flutuantes.
para corrigir esse problema utilize a fução toFixed presente nos numeros do tipo float passando como paramentro para a função o numero de casas decimais que deseja exibir, acho que ficaria bom o valor 2. Por exemplo:

```
var iniciaEm = 0;
var terminaEm = 20;
var variacao = 0.1;
var s = "";
var str = "";
for(var i =iniciaEm; i<=terminaEm;i+=variacao){
    str += i.toFixed(2)+"<br />"; 
    s += "<option value=\""+i.toFixed(2)+"%\">"+i.toFixed(2)+"%</option>";
}

$("#teste").append(s);
$(".resultado").append(str);
```