# O que acontece quando atribuímos um valor float a uma variável double?

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        double pi = 3.1415f;
        System.out.println(pi);
    }
}
```

Ao compilar e executar o código acima, obtive o retorno:
3.1414999961853027

Essa não é uma pergunta para resolução de um problema. 
Apenas gostaria de entender o que acontece aqui...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não está acontecendo nenhuma mágica aqui. É somente a forma que a informação está sendo exibida que acaba confundindo o usuário (desenvolvedor). Isso é a maneira que o `float` é implementado, quando você escreve `3.1415f` esse não é o valor real que será aplicado na variável, não é esse exatamente o valor encontrado na memória conforme a implementação do `float`. Você pode efetuar alguns testes:

```
float a = 3.1415f;
float b = 3.1414999961853027f;

System.out.println("a = " + a); // a = 3.1415
System.out.println("b = " + b); // b = 3.1415
System.out.println(a == b); // true
```

O valor exibido para ambos os casos que recebe um "arredondamento", mas o valor real encontrado na variável não é `3.1415f`. Esse "problema" não é muito comum de se encontrar quando se trabalha somente com `floats`, mas quando existe a coerção de valor de um `float` para um `double` as pessoas notam essa diferença porque o `double` acaba exibindo toda a informação, aparentando assim que os valores são diferentes (quando na verdade não são).

```
double c = a;
System.out.println("c = " + c); // c = 3.1414999961853027
```

Você pode [ver aqui](https://ideone.com/cxXm08) mais alguns testes provando que ambos os valores são exatamente iguais.

NOTA: Isso não é algo característico somente do `Java`, diversas linguagens implementam essa norma e os desenvolvedores geralmente sofrem com isso quando precisam de muita precisão. O C# implementa as mesmas normas para o `float` e o `double`, quando algo precisa de muita precisão como valores monetários eles possuem uma implementação `decimal` para suprir essas demandas. Outras linguagens como o `JavaScript` possuem somente uma implementação para representar números, e acabam [sofrendo com isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%C3%A1lculo-com-n%C3%BAmeros-quebrados), desde problemas com precisão até a representação de números grandes, necessitando de [bibliotecas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) para resolverem o problema.

Comment: *"mas quando existe a coerção de valor de um float para um double"* -  acho que você quis dizer "conversão", seria isso?

Comment: @diegofm "coerção" é conversão implícita, que é o caso da pergunta. Claro, usar o termo "conversão" deixa mais abrangente, mas eu acho estranho as pessoas quererem efetuar uma conversão explícita (cast) entre de "float" para "double".

Comment: Ah sim, era só pra "desencargo de consciência" mesmo :) A propósito, boa resposta, me tirou a dúvida também +1

Comment: @diegofm Sim, você está completamente correto em questionar. Se achar que tem algo de errado sempre questione. ;)

Comment: @Bacco resposta edita, obrigado pelo link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que as variáveis tem tamanhos diferentes:

`Float` Representa números em notação de ponto flutuante normalizada em precisão simples de **32 bits** em conformidade com a norma IEEE 754-1985. O menor valor positivo represntável por esse tipo é 1.40239846e-46 e o maior é 3.40282347e+38

`Double` Representa números em notação de ponto flutuante normalizada em precisão dupla de **64 bits** em conformidade com a norma IEEE 754-1985. O menor valor positivo representável é 4.94065645841246544e-324 e o maior é 1.7976931348623157e+308

Quando você faz a atribuição de um valor `double` em `float` ele trunca o valor para o tamanho suportado, metade do tamanho, diminuindo a precisão do valor. Apenas isso.

Veja mais informações em: http://www.dm.ufscar.br/~waldeck/curso/java/part22.html

Comment: Mas double é maior que float, como ele "trunca" se fizer cast de float pra double?

Comment: Ele não trunca o valor, isso está errado. Conversões implícitas (coerção) são conhecidas como conversões de alargamento, onde não existe perda de informação.

Comment: @diegofm quis dizer o contrário. Já corrigi.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura como citei, ele diminui a precisão, não disse que perde informações.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura isso de truncar deve ocorrer no inverso ne(um double muito grande para um float)

Comment: Celso, na pergunta, ele está atribuindo a uma variavel double, um valor float, e não ao inverso. Se float é 'menor' que double, como perde precisão?

Comment: Simplemente o não se aproveita a precisão maior na atribuição. Mas não perde nada. Se houve perda ocorreu antes, na hora de por o valor no float.

Comment: "Diminuir a precisão" no caso de `double` para `float` pode causar sim a perda de informação. Justamente por causa disto que conversões de estreitamento são feitas de forma explícita (casting).

Comment: @GabrielKatakura justamente, mas a pergunta é de float para double, acho que isso que está causando a confusão toda.

Comment: @Bacco estou ciente, só foi uma resposta referente ao "ele diminui a precisão, não disse que perde informações"

Comment: É fato que a precisão foi perdida, mas uma variável double, deveria ser capaz de armazenar um valor float sem problemas..
Acredito que foi na hora de converter o valor float < 3.1415f > para double, que a precisão foi perdida. 
O que eu queria mesmo era entender é por que a máquina não consegue simplesmente atribuir o valor 3.1415 (do float 3.1415f) à variável.

Comment: Tentei compilar usando casting 'double pi = (double) 3.1415f;'
Mas houve a mesma perda na precisão. (Estou realmente curioso para entender o que acontece aqui)

Comment: @IgorSantos isso nao acontece na conversão. É o jeito que números de ponto flutuante funcionam. Eles não "arredondam" em decimal http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%c3%a1lculo-com-n%c3%bameros-quebrados