# Formatar Nota para 2 casas Decimais

Tags: php, html

Recebendo quatro valores de inputs type *number* e fazendo algumas operações estou precisando que os retornos sejam formatados para sempre 2 casas decimais. Alguém tem alguma dica de como fazer, pois não consegui e com o `format_number` a formatação ficou com notação de moeda.

Segue código:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="form">
                <h1>Calculo de Notas - Pitágoras</h1>
                    <h2>Parcial 01</h2><br/>
                    <input type="number" name="input1" class="input" max="10" step=0.01 maxlength="5" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"><br/><br/>
                    <h2>Oficial 01</h2><br/>
                    <input type="number" name="input2" class="input" max="10" step=0.01 maxlength="5" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"><br/><br/>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($total) && !empty($total)){
                            if($total >= 7){
                                echo "<div class='resultadoPositivo resultado' >".$total."</div>";
                            } else{
                                echo "<div class='resultadoNegativo resultado'>".$total."</div>";
                            }
                        }

                    ?>
                    <h2>Parcial 02</h2><br/>
                    <input type="number" name="input3" class="input" max="10" step=0.01 maxlength="5" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"><br/><br/>
                    <h2>Oficial 02</h2><br/>
                    <input type="number" name="input4" class="input" max="10" step=0.01 maxlength="5" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"><br/><br/>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($total1) && !empty($total1)){
                            if($total1 >= 7){
                                echo "<div class='resultadoPositivo resultado'> ".$total1."</div>";
                            } else{
                                echo "<div class='resultadoNegativo resultado'>".$total1."</div>";
                            }
                        }

                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="enviar" class="botao">
                </form>
                    <div class="container grid-16 " id="resultado">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($final) && !empty($final)){
                            if($final >= 7){
                                echo "<div class='resultadoPositivo resultadoFinal'>O seu resultado final foi: ".$final."</div>";
                                echo "<div class='   resultadoFinal on'>Parabéns</div>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<div class='resultadoNegativo resultadoFinal'>O seu resultado final foi: ".$final."</div>";
                                echo "<div class=' resultadoFinal off'>Que Pena! </div>";
                            }
                        }

                    ?>
```

Segue PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['input1']) && !empty($_POST['input1'])){
    if(isset($_POST['input2']) && !empty($_POST['input2']) ){
        $nota1 = $_POST['input1'];
        $nota2 = $_POST['input2'];
        $total = ($nota1*0.3)+($nota2*0.7);

    }
}
if(isset($_POST['input3']) && !empty($_POST['input4'])){
    if(isset($_POST['input3']) && !empty($_POST['input4']) ){
        $nota1 = $_POST['input3'];
        $nota2 = $_POST['input4'];
        $total1 = ($nota1*0.3)+($nota2*0.7);

    }
}

if(isset($total) && !empty($total)){
    if(isset($total1) && !empty($total1)){
        $final = ($total*0.4)+($total1*0.6);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que está multiplicando você pode resolver dois problemas de uma vez só, usando o [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.bc.php), afinal [float contam "errado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%C3%A1lculo-com-n%C3%BAmeros-quebrados).

Então defina a quantidade de casas:

```
bcscale(2);
```

Depois faça:

```
$nota1 = $_POST['input1'];
$nota2 = $_POST['input2'];

$total = bcadd(bcmul($nota1, '0.3'), bcmul($nota2, 0.7));
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b85d6800a7257f51be1ac792369ed8a8fe9b90a)**

*Aplique o mesmo para os outros casos.* O `bcadd()` irá somar os resultados do `bcmul()`, todos eles terão duas casas definido por `bcscale()`.

---

Se quiser usar o `number_format`:

```
$nota1 = $_POST['input1'];
$nota2 = $_POST['input2'];

$total = ($nota1*0.3)+($nota2*0.7);

$total = number_format($total, 2, '.', '');
```

---

*Se quiser trocar o `.` por `,` mude para `number_format($total, 2, ',', '');`.*