# Encontrar conjunto de números em uma lista que juntos somam X

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso fazer um programa em que eu tenho uma lista de números 
(1571.48 | 327.53 | 286.60 | 349.50 | 517.67 | 247.00 | 882.73 | 274.00 | 237.50 | 301.00 | 973.50 | 288.75 | 347.50 | 326.81), e preciso achar no meio dessa lista, números que não repitam entre si e que juntos somem 4600.31 ou 2331.26. Eu fiz deste jeito, porém irá demorar uma eternidade para achar a combinação certa.

```
vetor = [1571.48, 327.53, 286.60,349.50,517.67,247.00,882.73,274.00,237.50,301.00,973.50,288.75,347.50,326.81]
for a in range(0,13):
    for b in range(0,13):
        if vetor[a] + vetor[b] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] == 4600.31:
            print ("%s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[a] + vetor[b]))
        for c in range(0,13):
            if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] == 4600.31:
                print ("%s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c]))
            for d in range(0,13):
                if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] == 4600.31:
                    print ("%s + %s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d]))
                for e in range(0,13):
                    if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] == 4600.31:
                        print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d],vetor[e], vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e]))
                    for f in range(0,13):
                        if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] == 4600.31:
                            print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f], vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f]))
                        for g in range(0,13):
                            if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] == 4600.31:
                                print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f], vetor[g], vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g]))
                            for h in range(0,13):
                                if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] == 4600.31:
                                    print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f], vetor[g], vetor[h], vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h]))
                                for i in range(0,13):
                                    if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] == 4600.31:
                                        print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f], vetor[g], vetor[h],vetor[i],vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i]))
                                    for j in range(0,13):
                                        if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] == 4600.31:
                                            print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s = %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f], vetor[g],vetor[h], vetor[i],vetor[j],vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j]))
                                        for k in range(0,13):
                                            if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] == 4600.31:
                                                print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f], vetor[g],vetor[h], vetor[i], vetor[j],vetor[k]))
                                            for l in range(0,13):
                                                if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] + vetor[l] == 4600.31:
                                                    print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f],vetor[g], vetor[h], vetor[i], vetor[j], vetor[k], vetor[l]))
                                                for m in range(0,13):
                                                    if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] + vetor[m] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] +vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] + vetor[l] + vetor[m] == 4600.31:
                                                        print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f],vetor[g], vetor[h], vetor[i], vetor[j], vetor[k], vetor[l], vetor[m]))
                                                    for n in range(0,13):
                                                        if vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] + vetor[m] + vetor[n] == 2331.26 or vetor[a] + vetor[b] + vetor[c] + vetor[d] + vetor[e] + vetor[f] + vetor[g] + vetor[h] + vetor[i] + vetor[j] + vetor[k] + vetor[m] + vetor[n] == 4600.31:
                                                            print ("%s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s + %s" % (vetor[a], vetor[b], vetor[c], vetor[d], vetor[e], vetor[f], vetor[g], vetor[h], vetor[i], vetor[j],vetor[k], vetor[l], vetor[m], vetor[n]))
```

Alguém teria uma dica de forma ou até mesmo biblioteca para mim poder otimizar o programa, pois eu acredito que assim demorará mais de dias.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o problema. Pode explicar melhor a parte de números que se repetem e que somam 4600.31 ou 2331.26? Se possível, apresente um exemplo de quais seriam esses números na lista.

Comment: Uma dica: se tem 2 níveis de aninhamento de laço pense se não pode melhorar. Se tem 3 ou 4 tem grande chance de ter algo errado aí. Se tiver tiver 5 ou mais eu diria que está errado mesmo que tenha necessidade. Não é questão de biblioteca, é questão de resolver o problema de outra maneira, mas não está claro o que deseja. Este parece ser um caso que dá para fazer com `for` e talvez que tem como otimizar para virar um mais complexo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a lista de números é 
327.53 | 286.60 | 349.50 | 517.67 | 247.00 | 882.73 | 274.00 | 237.50 | 301.00 | 973.50 | 288.75 | 347.50 | 326.81

Comment: @Hebert, sim, a lista é a única coisa que ficou clara na pergunta; o que não ficou claro é o que quis dizer com "números que se repetem" e "que somam 4600.31 ou 2331.26". Explique essas partes e **dê exemplos** de qual seria a saída desejada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss
Por exemplo:

Eu tenho uma lista de números: (25, 35, 60, 75, 90) e o resultado da soma precisa ser: 135, então o programa vai fazer diversas tentativas até que ele vai chegar na tentativa 60+75, e vai resultar 135, e dai o programa vai printar os números que foram usados para efetuar a soma e o resultado final.

Só que ao invés de (25, 35, 60, 75, 90) é a lista que eu te passei, e ao invés do resultado final ser 135 é 4600.31 ou 2331.26, entendeu agora?

Comment: E "números que não se repitam entre si" seria que a combinação 60+60 não fosse considerada, mesmo que resultasse no valor desejado?

Comment: Implementei a lógica e nenhuma das combinações de valores da lista presente na pergunta resulta em uma soma igual a um dos valores esperados. Isso está certo? Alguma das combinações deveria resultar nesta soma?

Comment: Sim, 60+60 não poderia aparecer assim como 25 + 25 + 60 ou 60 + 75 + 90 + 90 não poderia ser considerado também, por erro meu eu esqueci um número na lista original que é 1571.48, e era esperado que alguma combinação resultasse 4600.31 ou 2331.26, lembrando que poderia ser uma soma com 2 (327.53 + 286.60) números ou uma soma com 5 (327.53 + 286.60 + 349.50 + 517.67 + 247.00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O módulo `itertools` possui a função `combinations`, que gera uma determinada combinação a partir dos elementos de um objeto iterável. Isto é, ao fazermos `combinations('stack', 3)`, teremos todas as combinações 3 a 3 das letras que formam a palavra "stack".

Como o número de elementos na combinação deve mudar, isto é, combinar 1 a 1, depois 2 a 2, depois 3 a 3, etc, devemos gerar todas as combinações possíveis desde 1 até o comprimento da lista inicial.

Fazemos isso desta forma:

```
from itertools import combinations

numbers = [1571.48, 327.53, 286.60, 349.50, 517.67, 247.00, 882.73, 274.00, 237.50, 301.00, 973.50, 288.75, 347.50, 326.81]

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for combination in combinations(numbers, i):
        if sum(combination) in {4600.31, 2331.26}:
            print('A soma de ', combination, 'resultou em', sum(combination))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/37UAaN) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/VibrantUntidyGallinule)</sup>

Ou seja, geramos todas as combinações possíveis e se a soma desta combinação for 4600.31 ou 2331.26, exibimos uma mensagem. Se executar este código, o resultado será que nenhuma combinação possui tal soma. Isso acontece porque estamos trabalhando com números com ponto flutuante, então não podemos comparar a igualdade de dois valores; sempre existe a possibilidade de ocorrer algum erro de arredondamento devido à representação do valor na memória e pode ser que a soma, ao invés de dar exatamente o valor, chegue muito próximo.

A forma mais fácil de contornar isso seria definir um possível desvio do valor; algo como: se a soma dos valores na combinação subtraída do valor desejado ser menor que 1, então podemos considerar que a soma foi o valor desejado. Em código, isso ficaria assim:

```
from itertools import combinations

numbers = [1571.48, 327.53, 286.60, 349.50, 517.67, 247.00, 882.73, 274.00, 237.50, 301.00, 973.50, 288.75, 347.50, 326.81]

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for combination in combinations(numbers, i):
        s = sum(combination)
        if abs(s - 4600.31) < 1 or abs(s - 2331.26) < 1:
            print('A soma de ', combination, 'resultou em', s)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/zjC2LW) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ProductiveWellinformedEyra)</sup>

O resultado deste código é:

```
A soma de  (1571.48, 327.53, 517.67, 882.73, 973.5, 326.81) resultou em 4599.72
A soma de  (327.53, 286.6, 349.5, 247.0, 882.73, 237.5) resultou em 2330.86
A soma de  (327.53, 247.0, 882.73, 237.5, 288.75, 347.5) resultou em 2331.01
A soma de  (286.6, 349.5, 882.73, 274.0, 237.5, 301.0) resultou em 2331.33
A soma de  (247.0, 882.73, 237.5, 288.75, 347.5, 326.81) resultou em 2330.29
A soma de  (882.73, 274.0, 237.5, 301.0, 288.75, 347.5) resultou em 2331.48
A soma de  (1571.48, 286.6, 349.5, 247.0, 882.73, 973.5, 288.75) resultou em 4599.5599999999995
A soma de  (1571.48, 286.6, 882.73, 237.5, 301.0, 973.5, 347.5) resultou em 4600.3099999999995
A soma de  (327.53, 349.5, 517.67, 247.0, 274.0, 288.75, 326.81) resultou em 2331.2599999999998
A soma de  (327.53, 517.67, 274.0, 237.5, 301.0, 347.5, 326.81) resultou em 2332.0099999999998
A soma de  (1571.48, 327.53, 286.6, 349.5, 517.67, 247.0, 973.5, 326.81) resultou em 4600.090000000001
A soma de  (1571.48, 327.53, 286.6, 349.5, 517.67, 274.0, 301.0, 973.5) resultou em 4601.280000000001
A soma de  (1571.48, 327.53, 517.67, 247.0, 973.5, 288.75, 347.5, 326.81) resultou em 4600.240000000001
A soma de  (1571.48, 286.6, 349.5, 517.67, 274.0, 301.0, 973.5, 326.81) resultou em 4600.56
A soma de  (1571.48, 517.67, 274.0, 301.0, 973.5, 288.75, 347.5, 326.81) resultou em 4600.71
A soma de  (286.6, 349.5, 247.0, 274.0, 237.5, 301.0, 288.75, 347.5) resultou em 2331.85
```

Perceba que nenhuma soma resultou exatamente nos valores esperados, mas chegaram bem próximos.

Leia mais em [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/5878)

Comment: Obrigado pela resolução do problema de jeito pratico e bem diferente do meu.

Na parte de erro do número final não ser exatamente o que eu disse deve ter sido algum erro meu, mas do mesmo jeito obrigado :)

Comment: @Hebert e o tempo de execução... Você deve ter visto o tempo que seu código demorava para executar.

Comment: Sim, o meu ficava eternidades para responder algo