# Como é feito a conversão de String para Float no Core do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, conversão-de-tipo

Sempre tive a curiosidade de saber como realmente funciona a conversão de `string` para `float` internamente no [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), por isso gostaria de receber uma resposta completa e detalhada explicando o que o javascript faz internamente no momento da conversão para produzir o resultado obtido.

Comment: A [especificação EcmaScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3) define o algoritmo exato utilizado pelo `parseFloat`, cuja implementação exata depende do engine

Answer (score 1):

A função responsável por fazer a conversão é a [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) e não está associada a nenhum objeto. `Number.parseFloat` é a mesma usada por `parseFloat`. A [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parsefloat-string) determina como algoritmo funciona, mas a implementação pode ser **diferente** dependendo da **Engine Javascript**.

### Especificação (Tradução) do algoritmo

A função `parseFloat` produz um valor numérico ditado pela interpretação do conteúdo do argumento da *string* como decimal literal.
Quando a função `parseFloat` é chamada com um argumento *string*, os seguintes passos são tomados:

1. Deixe *inputString* ser `toString`
2. `ReturnIfAbrupt` *nota: O termo conclusão abrupta (repentina) refere-se a qualquer conclusão com o valor tipo diferente do normal*
3. Deixe *trimmedString* ser uma substring de *inputString* consistindo na unidade de código mais à esquerda que não seja *StrWhiteSpaceChar* e todas as unidades de código à direita da unidade de código. (Em outras palavras, remove os espaços em branco). Se *inputString* não contém nenhum tipo de unidade de código, deixe *trimmedString* ser uma string vazia.
4. Se nem *trimmedString* nem algum prefixo de *trimmedString* satisfaz a sintaxe de *StrDecimalLiteral*, retorne *NaN*
5. Deixe *numberString* ser o prefixo mais longo de *trimmedString*, que pode ser *trimmedString* mesmo, que satisfaz a sintaxe de um *StrDecimalLiteral*
6. Deixe *mathFloat* ser MV de *numberString*
7. Se *mathFloat=0*, então

   a. Se a primeira unidade de código de *trimmedString* é "-", returne -0

   b. Retorne +0
8. Retorne o valor numérico para *mathFloat*

   NOTA: `parseFloat` talvez interprete somente a parte principal da *string* como um valor numérico; ele ignora qualquer unidade de código que não pode ser interpretado como parte da notação de um literal decimal, e nenhuma indicação é dada quando alguma unidade de código foi ignorada.

---

O algoritmo especifica a chamada de outras funções nativas no seu fluxo, como `trim()` por exemplo.

Comment: Boa resposta, porém eu particularmente achei meio confuso de entender o funcionamento, talvez fosse melhor expor o código da implementação.