# "for" com step "float": TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, for, float

Quero fazer um loop de 0 a 100 com step 0.1:

```
for x in range(0, 100, 0.1):
    a = cos(radians(x))
```

Mas eu recebo este erro:

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Como posso fazer um loop com step float?

Comment: Já pensou em implementar um `generator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui fazer algo que possivelmente seja o que você necessita.

```
from math import cos, radians

for x in (x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 1000)):
    print(x)
    a = cos(radians(x))

print(a)
```

Código ficaria algo nesse sentido

**SUGESTÃO**

A utilização de um número decimal neste caso pode acarretar em possíveis erros com a questão do ponto flutuante. Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Numpy](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html) fazendo uso da função **arange** que funciona de forma parecida ao for.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])
```

**Dica Extra**

Para evitar a questão de erro com ponto flutuante, pode-se utilizar a função **linspace** do Numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ])
```

**Fonte:** https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html

Comment: Ok, editei o exemplo acima para ficar mais claro. Não vejo sentido em usar numpy se eu quero apenas calcular o `cos` de cada número no intervalo de `0.1`... teria alguma outra forma?

Comment: @RogérioDec editei a resposta, espero que possa ter solucionado seu problema

Comment: No primeiro exemplo `for x in [x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 1000)]:`, é melhor `for x in (x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 1000)):` - esse segundo é um "generator expression":  cada elemento só é criado quando for ser usado no `for`. Com `[ ] `, o Python cria primeiro uma lista com todos os elementos - alocando memória pra tudo, e só depois consome os elementos no laço `for` externo. A diferença de consumo de memória é significativa.

Comment: @jsbueno sim verdade, não me atentei nesse ponto.

Answer (score 2):

Somente para fins de amostragem perceba a inconsistência do resultado dessa implementação de um gerador que realiza a soma de números inteiros e de ponto flutuante.

```
def _range(initial, end = float("inf"), step = 1):
    act = initial
    while (act < end):
        yield act
        act += step

for x in _range(0, 1, 0.1):
    print(x)

0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

Leia essa resposta para mais informações: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11328/88315

Answer (score 0):

É possível alcançar o resultado desejado usando um gerador de *ints* e dividir o resultado:

```
    for x in range(1001):
         x = x/10
         print(x)
```

> > > 0.0
> > >
> > > 0.1
> > >
> > > 0.2
> > >
> > > (...)
> > >
> > > 99.9
> > >
> > > 100.0
> > >
> > > [Finished in 0.196s]