# Erro no calculo de resto da divisão

Tags: divisão

Estou estudando e montando programas.
Tem uma parte que coloquei

```py
     if litro % 3.6 == 0:
```

E quando `litro=36`, o resultado não tem que ser `true`?
Pois `36/3.6=10` e não sobra nada.

Mas quando coloco isso no programa o valor fica `3.59999999....`
Quando eu coloco

```py
     55%5.5 == 0
```

o resultado é `true`.

Eu quero saber por que `55%5.5` fica `0` e `36%3.6` não...

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Possível duplicata [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%c3%a1lculo-com-n%c3%bameros-quebrados)

Answer (score 3):

De modo geral, é tudo consequência de entender [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969) e suas consequências.

Por incrível que pareça, exceto se você mandar usar um sistema numérico próprio, ao usar um número com vírgulas, você estará usando um número de ponto flutuante binário, normalmente `float` ou `double`. Cada um tem sua especificação definida pela IEEE, mais especificamente IEEE 754.

Então, vamos lá. Vou fazer uma afirmação dura, mas verdadeira: não existe o número `3.6` no sistema numérico usado (que é ponto flutuante binário), porém existe `5.5`. Assista a [este vídeo (em inglês)](https://youtu.be/pQs_wx8eoQ8) para entender melhor sobre o assunto.

Quando eu digo que "não existe no sistema numérico" estou me referindo a uma representação **finita**; em uma dízima periódica (que se estende ao infinito e além) há representação.

Para entender isso, e poder provar, primeiro se necessita entender que o ponto flutuante binário é uma espécie de notação científica usando apenas os dígitos binários. Então, `5.5` é representado, finitamente, por `1.011 * 2^2`. Como eu cheguei a essa conclusão? Segue abaixo:

A maior potência de 2 que cabe em `5.5` é `4`, que é `2^2`. Assim, o primeiro dígito da notação científica é `1` e o expoente é `2^2` (já que estamos trabalhando em dígitos binários). Assim, após removermos `4` sobra `1.5`; a próxima potência é `2^1 = 2`, porém não cabe nesse resto, logo agora temos `1.0` na mantissa, o expoente não mudará e continuará como `2^2` e precisamos ainda encaixar `1.5`. A próxima potência é `2^0 = 1`, e esse número cabe dentro de `1.5`, logo temos a mantissa de `1.01` em construção, faltando encaixar `0.5`. Em seguida, a próxima potência é `2^-1 = 0.5`, que cabe **exatamente** em `0.5`, resultando na mantissa `1.011` e expoente de `2^2`. Um quadro resumindo esse teste de mesa segue abaixo:

```
passo           | 0       | 1       | 2       | 3
potência        | 2^2 = 4 | 2^1 = 2 | 2^0 = 1 | 2^-1 = 0.5
resto anterior  | 5.5     | 1.5     | 1.5     | 0.5
cabe no resto?  | S       | N       | S       | S
resto novo      | 1.5     | 1.5     | 0.5     | 0
mantissa        | 1       | 1.0     | 1.01    | 1.011
```

E se fizéssemos isso para `3.6`? Bem, a maior potência de 2 que cabe dentro desse número é `2^1 = 2`. Vamos por no teste de mesa?

```
passo           | 0       | 1       | 2          | 3           | 4            | 5             | 6
potência        | 2^1 = 2 | 2^0 = 1 | 2^-1 = 0.5 | 2^-2 = 0.25 | 2^-3 = 0.125 | 2^-4 = 0.0625 | 2^-5 = 0.03125
resto anterior  | 3.6     | 1.6     | 0.6        | 0.1         | 0.1          | 0.1           | 0.0375
cabe no resto?  | S       | S       | S          | N           | N            | S             | S
resto novo      | 1.6     | 0.6     | 0.1        | 0.1         | 0.1          | 0.0375        | 0.00625
mantissa        | 1       | 1.1     | 1.11       | 1.110       | 1.1100       | 1.11001       | 1.110011
```

O teste começou a se tornar bem oneroso, não é? Eu posso adiantar que o decimal `0.1` não pode ser representado por uma quantidade finita de casas binárias, logo a gente acabaria em uma dízima periódica (que no caso para `0.1` em decimal é `0.0[0011]` em binário, onde os números [entre colchetes] são a parte que se repete da dízima). Vide [1](https://www.quora.com/What-is-0-1-in-binary) [2](https://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/) [3](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/).

Para complicar a vida, qualquer inteiro pode ser representado como a soma de potências inteiras de 2. Logo, o número `36` tem representação exata. A maior potência de 2 que cabe em `36` é `2^5 = 32`. Aplicando aquele teste de mesa obtemos o seguinte:

```
passo           | 0        | 1        | 2       | 3
potência        | 2^5 = 32 | 2^4 = 16 | 2^3 = 8 | 2^2 = 4
resto anterior  | 36       | 4        | 4       | 4
cabe no resto?  | S        | N        | N       | S
resto novo      | 4        | 4        | 4       | 0
mantissa        | 1        | 1.0      | 1.00    | 1.001
```

Logo, `36` em decimal pode ser escrito como `1.001 * 2^5` em notação científica binária, que pode ser transformado em um inteiro binário `100100`.

---

Então, voltando ao foco da questão: você tem um número de representação finita (`36`) sendo dividido por uma aproximação da representação infinita de outro número (`3.6`, cuja aproximação binária eu não consigo expressar aqui). Como o divisor não é mais o número exato, mas uma aproximação dele, o dividendo não será mais múltiplo do divisor. Então, haverá, sim, resto na divisão.

Comment: Hum.....Muito obrigado!!!!!!!!!
Não totalmente, mas conseguir entender.
Nas próximas programações que irei fazer, tomarei cuidado com isso para não dar erro no final.