# Porque se somar 0.2 e 0.1 é retornado um número bem grande?

Tags: javascript

No exemplo abaixo se somar `0.3` mais `0.3` ele vai me retornar obviamente `0.6`:

```js
console.log(0.3 + 0.3);
```

Mas ao tentar soma `0.2` mais `0.1` ele não me retorna o resultado como `0.3` e sim um número enorme como `0.30000000000000004`:

```js
console.log(0.2 + 0.1)
```

Eu encontrei uma solução que é fazer a seguinte operação:

```js
console.log((0.2 * 10 + 0.1 * 10) / 10);
```

Mas eu não entendi o porque do *JavaScript* me retornar um número enorme?

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%c3%a1lculo-com-n%c3%bameros-quebrados)

Comment: Não é um número enorme, é um número não-arredondado. Internamente os números de ponto flutuante são representados em binário com um número fixo de dígitos. Nem 0.2 nem 0.1 têm um valor exato em binário de ponto flutuante, então eles são armazenados com um pequeno erro. Quando você soma, a soma dos erros fica grande o suficiente para aparecer na impressão em decimal. Se você quer garantir que isso não aconteça, tem de trabalhar com números inteiros, ou forçar um arredondamento tipo (0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(2)