# Como usar javascript para realizar operação matemática

Tags: javascript, java, variáveis, lógica

Eu tenho a seguinte relação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu crio um código em javascript que faça a conta dos decimais? Por exemplo... se eu medir 5,7cm?

A conta que faria seria: subtrair 110 de 145 e o resultado dividir por 10. Dessa forma eu teria o valor de cada milímetro. Então basta multiplicar por 7 (do 5,7cm) e somar ao valor em litros associado ao 5cm, ou seja, 110 litros.

O resultado seria 134,50 litros.

Eu precisava de um código em javascript que faça essa conta. Alguém consegue me ajudar nesse doideira?

Comment: Tens esses numeros da tabela em texto? por exemplo num objeto?

Comment: Seja bem vinda, queira editar sua questão e acrescentar o código que estar a tentar... Considere fazer um [tour] para tirar melhor proveito da comunidade. Boa sorte;)

Comment: Então... na verdade eu quero fazer uma coisa bem doida. Não tenho tanto conhecimento de java, então fiz um frankestein com uns modelos que achei na internet.

Basicamente o que eu queria era colocar o valor em cm (inclusive com os decimais 57,4 ou 35,9 e etc) e a página me retornar o valor (litros) correspondente.

Até o momento eu consegui fazer puxar os números inteiros, mas preciso dos decimais. Veja o projeto aqui https://gol-dolm.github.io/CalcD/

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a tua lógica matemática, podes usar o `Math.floor` para obter a parte inteira arredondada por baixo, e o `Math.ceil` para arredondar para cima. Depois usas o `%` para extrair a parte decimal (com algum código extra [porque o JavaScript precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11328/129)) e tens o que precisas!

Um exemplo seria:

```js
// cm : litros
const escala = {
  "1": 10,
  "2": 28,
  "3": 51,
  "4": 79,
  "5": 110,
  "6": 145,
  "7": 182,
  "8": 222,
  "9": 265,
  "10": 310
};

function calcularLitragem(cm) {
  const valorInferior = Math.floor(cm);
  const valorSuperior = Math.ceil(cm);
  const parteDecimal = Number((cm % 1).toFixed(3));

  return escala[valorSuperior] - escala[valorInferior] / 10 * parteDecimal;
}
console.log(calcularLitragem(5)); // 110
console.log(calcularLitragem(5.7)); // 137.3
console.log(calcularLitragem(6)); // 145
```

Comment: Não tenho tanto conhecimento de java, então fiz um frankestein com uns modelos que achei na internet. Basicamente o que eu queria era colocar o valor em cm (inclusive com os decimais 57,4 ou 35,9 e etc) e a página me retornar o valor (litros) correspondente. Até o momento eu consegui fazer puxar os números inteiros, mas preciso dos decimais. Veja o projeto aqui https://gol-dolm.github.io/CalcD/